# Bash - find exec return value

Tags: linux, bash

I need a way to tell if grep does find something, and ideally pass that return value to an if statement.

Let's say I have a `tmp` folder (current folder), in that there are several files and sub-folders. I want to search all files named `abc` for a pattern `xyz`. The search is assumed to be successful if it finds any occurrence of `xyz` (it does not matter how many times `xyz` is found). The search fails if no occurrence of `xyz` is found.

In bash, it can be done like this:

```
find . -name "abc" -exec grep "xyz" {} \;
```

That would show if `xyz` is found at all. But I'm not sure how pass the result (successful or not) back to an `if` statement.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that your example shows usage of the `find` command, and has nothing in particular to do with bash.  Where is your `if` statement, and how do you want to use the output of your search?

Comment: Are you looking to know about the result for each file separately, or collectively (the difference between "does every file `abc` contain the text `xyz`" and "does at least one file `abc` contain the text `xyz`")?

Comment: Collectively - thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
x=`find . -name abc | xargs grep xyz`
echo $x
```

Or, to properly handle whitespaces and endlines in filenames:

```
x=`find . -name abc -print0 | xargs -0 grep xyz`
echo $x
```

That is, x contains your return value. It is blank when there is no match.

Comment: Just to be clear, the `echo x` part is just for you to test. Then you need to figure out how to use an if statement in bash,  which should  be easy for you to find out. If not then you can ask about this topic.

Comment: Right, then checking if the results is empty or not seems to do the trick for this case: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061036/how-to-find-variable-is-empty-or-in-shell-script

Comment: This is somewhat unsophisticated, and needlessly collects the list of matching files.  If you really want to know which files matched, piping the output from `find -exec grep` to a loop over those file names is usually more natural.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know that `find` finds some files `abc` and that at least one of them contains the string `xyz`, then you can probably use:

```
if find . -name 'abc' -type f -exec grep -q xyz {} +
then : All invocations of grep found at least one xyz and nothing else failed
else : One or more invocations of grep failed to find xyz or something else failed
fi
```

This relies on `find` returning an exit status for its own operations, and a non-zero exit status of any of the command(s) it executes.  The `+` at the end groups as many file names as `find` thinks reasonable into a single command line.  You need quite a lot of file name (a large number of fairly long names) to make `find` run `grep` multiple times.  On a Mac running Mac OS X 10.10.4, I got to about 3,000 files, each with about 32 characters in the name, for an argument list of just over 100 KiB, without `grep` being run multiple times.  OTOH, when I had just under 8000 files, I got two runs of `grep`, with around 130 KiB of argument list for each.

Someone briefly left a comment asking whether the exit status of [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) is guaranteed. The answer is 'yes' — though I had to modify my description of the exit status a bit.  Under the description of `-exec`, POSIX specifies:

> If any invocation *[of the 'utility', such as `grep` in this question]* returns a non-zero value as exit status, the `find` utility shall return a non-zero exit status.

And under the general 'Exit status' it says:

> The following exit values shall be returned:
>
> `0` —  All path operands were traversed successfully.
> `>0` —  An error occurred.

Thus, `find` will report success as long as none of its own operations fails and as long as none of the `grep` commands it invokes fails.  Zero files found but no failures will be reported as success.  (Failures might be lack of permission to search a directory, for example.)

Comment: If you want more control over the exit code, maybe use `xargs`, which returns a bit more details.

Answer (score 1):

find returns the result of the `-exec`'d command as its result, just place the command in an if statement:

```
if [[ -n $(find . -name "abc" -exec grep "xyz" {} \;) ]]
then
   # do something
fi
```

Comment: @artm There is a better explanation here than I could provide: http://serverfault.com/questions/52034/what-is-the-difference-between-double-and-single-square-brackets-in-bash. Are you pointing to /bin/sh? You said bash that is why I used `[[ .. ]]`.

Answer (score 1):

The `grep` command can be given a `-q` option that will "quiet" its output.  Grep will return a success or a failure on the basis of whether it found anything in the file you pointed it at.

If your shell is capable of it, rather than trying to parse the output of a `find` command, you might want to try using a `for` loop instead.  For example in bash:

```
shopt -s globstar

cd /some/directory

for file in **/abc; do
  grep -q "xyz" "$file" && echo "Found something in $file"
done
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with just grep with `--include` I believe.

Like this:

```
if grep -r --include=abc -q xyz; then
    : Found at least one match
else
    : No matching lines found
fi
```

Comment: thanks - seems to work on normal grep; unfortunately the grep version in busybox doesn't support  either option `-r` or `--include`