# find + grep as an if condition doesn't work as expected

Tags: shell, grep, find

I use `find` to get all `txt` files , then use `grep` to find if a special word in the `txt` files which find by `find` command.

```sh
if find "/home/test/" -name "*.csv" -exec grep "pattern" {} \;; then
    echo "find it in txt files";
else
    echo "not find in txt files";
fi
```

The program always outputs `"find it"` although the conditions are not met.

Comment: *-name* must be quoted to prevent shell globbing. to get exit status you could use *\\( -exec grep ... {} \; -a -exec echo ... \; \\)*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash - find exec return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713189/bash-find-exec-return-value)

Comment: Do you want to print `find it` if `pattern` is matched in any file or if it's matched in all files?

Answer (score 2):

Unless punctuated by a plus sign, an **-exec** predicate doesn't affect **find**'s exit status. See:

```
$ find . -prune -exec test -f {} ';'
$ echo $?
0
$ find . -prune -exec test -f {} '+'
$ echo $?
1
```

But even with the plus sign, **find**'s exit status is unreliable. It may invoke **grep** multiple times due to memory limitations, and if any invocation exits with a non-zero value, **find**'s exit status will also be non-zero. In other words, if all invocations of **grep** find a match but one doesn't, **find**'s exit status will not be zero. This applies to **xargs** as well.

Here is a way to walk around these constraints:

```
! find . -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c '! "$@"' _ grep 'pattern' /dev/null {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

`find` exits normally if all files found are processed. Specifically, this ignores the return code of the command executed.

If you want the exit code of `grep`, you're better off with `xargs`, which can send the output of `find` as command-line arguments to `grep`. For example:

```sh
find ./ -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0r grep "pattern"
```

This has the advantage that you can still customize `find` parameters over `grep -r`.

Of course you can use GNU grep with `--exclude` and `--include` for similar features, but `find` is more powerful for its expressions.

Comment: Thanks, I try to use  the command `if find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name '*asdfasd*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0r grep "asdfqwerytavasdf" ; then echo "find it"; else echo "not find"; fi` to test if it right. I find  if the `find` command returns an empty file list,  the console will show `find it`, But I like it show `not find`. How to deal with this problem?

Comment: I debug the `if` command ? So I first input  `find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name '*asdfasd*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0r grep "asdfqwerytavasdf"`  in console, then input `echo $?`, the console output  `0` , I very confused about this result, since the output  is `0` , above `if` command need output `not find`

Comment: I write a shell program, find the empty variable is true in  `if` command...