# How can I check if a variables holds 'nothing'

Tags: bash, text-processing

I'm comparing information between a csv database and PHP table. There are some instances where the PHP table has 'blank' or 'empty' value.

How can I make sure that the comparisons in my `if` statement actually compare two values as opposed to one value being compared to a 'blank' value?

This is the snippet of code

```
if [ "$CSV_PartDir" == "$PHP_PartDir" ] && [ "$CSV_PartName" == "$PHP_PartName" ]
then
    echo "MATCH:[$direction / $PHP_PartDir]  PN: [$part_name / $PHP_PartNam]"
    match=$((match+1))
elif [ "$CSV_PartDir" != "$PHP_PartDir" ] && [ "$CSV_PartName" != "$PHP_PartName" ]
then 
    echo "WRONG: [$direction / $PHP_PartDir]  PN: [$part_name / $PHP_PartNam]"
    mismatch=$((mismatch+1))
fi
```

This is a sample OUTPUT:

```
MATCH:[OUT / OUT]  PN: [JSP-015123 / JSP-015123]
MATCH:[OUT / OUT]  PN: [02118 / 02118]
MATCH:[OUT / OUT]  PN: [02132 / 02132]
MATCH:[OUT / OUT]  PN: [JSP-015123 / JSP-015123]
MATCH:[OUT / OUT]  PN: [JSP-015123 / JSP-015123]
WRONG: [OUT / ]  PN: [02132 / ]
WRONG: [OUT / ]  PN: [02132 / ]
WRONG: [OUT / IN ]  PN: [OH-VPS-023 / JSP-01512 ] <--- a "legitimate" comparison to be define as "wrong"
WRONG: [OUT / ]  PN: [02132 / ]   <--- NOT a "legitimate" comparison to be define as "wrong"
```

**Q:** Is there a certain way of checking that the `PHP_PartName` and/or `PHP_PartDir` actually holds a value as opposed nothing within the `if`.

*Ideally* I would like to print out "wrong" or "mismatch" should my PHP values and CSV values don't match. So I would like to suppress the empty values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to find variable is empty or "" in shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061036/how-to-find-variable-is-empty-or-in-shell-script)

Comment: You want to say `MATCH` if one of them is blank, instead of `WRONG`?

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the `test` command, specifically the `-z` test for null, and the `-n` test for NOT NULL.

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest

Answer (score 0):

Use the syntax for substituting a default value if a variable is unset or null, and use the value of the variable you're comparing with as the default:

```
if [ "${CSV_PartDir:-$PHP_PartDir}" = "${PHP_PartDir:-$CSV_PartDir}" ] && [ "${CSV_PartName:-$PHP_PartName}" = "${PHP_PartName:-$CSV_PartName}" ]
```

So if one of the variables is is empty, it will default to the other variable, and they'll match instead of saying `WRONG`.