# Bash conditionals: how to "and" expressions? (if [ ! -z $VAR && -e $VAR ])

Tags: bash, shell

I guess I'm not clear on how to do "and" tests. I wanted to make sure an argument existed which was working well with `[ -e $VAR ]`, but it turns out that was also evaluating as true on an empty string; which I do not want.

How do I 'and' them together? Or is there another unary test that accomplishes what I want?

Answer (score 538, accepted):

```
if [ ! -z "$var" ] && [ -e "$var" ]; then
      # something ...
fi
```

Comment: This solution works even in strictly POSIX-compliant shells and therefore also in `bash`; however, to take full advantage of "bashisms", see @paxdiablo's answer.

Comment: Very glad to see this advised instead of the obsolescent `-a`.

Comment: I found another one excellent and detailed explanation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash

Answer (score 72):

From the `bash` manpage:

> `[[ expression ]]` - return  a status of 0 or 1 depending on the evaluation of the conditional expression expression.

And, for expressions, one of the options is:

> `expression1 && expression2` - true if both `expression1` and `expression2` are true.

So you can `and` them together as follows (`-n` is the opposite of `-z` so we can get rid of the `!`):

```
if [[ -n "$var" && -e "$var" ]] ; then
    echo "'$var' is non-empty and the file exists"
fi
```

However, I don't think it's needed in this case, `-e xyzzy` is true if the `xyzzy` *file* exists and can quite easily handle empty strings. If that's what you want then you don't actually need the `-z` non-empty check:

```
pax> VAR=xyzzy
pax> if [[ -e $VAR ]] ; then echo yes ; fi
pax> VAR=/tmp
pax> if [[ -e $VAR ]] ; then echo yes ; fi
yes
```

In other words, just use:

```
if [[ -e "$var" ]] ; then
    echo "'$var' exists"
fi
```

Comment: We can shorten it with `[[ -e "$var" ]] && echo "'$var' exists"`

Comment: Yes, if it's a one-liner (as my example was). I wouldn't do that if the conditional block was much more complex though.

Comment: in case there is only one - maybe even long one - command, it makes sense to use this form as it is shorter

Answer (score 9):

```
if [ -n "$var" -a -e "$var" ]; then
    do something ...
fi
```

Comment: Since `POSIX` doesn't define the behavior of `[` with complex sets of tests, we should avoid using `-a` or `-o` with `[`. I read it [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals?highlight=%28conditional%29#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29).

Comment: @jaypal-singh You are right, but topic has `bash` tag and not mention about POSIX, so I post this version which works under `bash` and some other modern shells.

Comment: If you are assuming the use of `bash` or other modern shells, there is even *less* reason to recommend `-a`.

Comment: Even with bash, the way these tests behave is not well-defined in all corner cases. Consider `[ "$var1" -o "$var2" ]`; if `var1=(` and `var2=)`, then what we have is a test for whether `-o` is non-empty, rather than whether either of `var1` or `var2` is non-empty. This kind of ambiguity is the only legitimate reason for the `x$var` idiom in modern (that is, post-90s) `test` commands with correct quoting, and that idiom needs to die in a fire.

Answer (score 4):

Simply quote your variable:

```
[ -e "$VAR" ]
```

This evaluates to `[ -e "" ]` if `$VAR` is empty.

Your version does not work because it evaluates to `[ -e ]`. Now in this case, bash simply checks if the single argument (`-e`) is a non-empty string.

From the manpage:

> test and [ evaluate conditional expressions using a set of rules based on the number of arguments. ...
>
> 1 argument
>
> The expression is true if and only if the argument is not null.

(Also, this solution has the additional benefit of working with filenames containing spaces)

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer now. Thanks for your suggestions!

```
for e in ./*.cutoff.txt; do
if grep -q -E 'COX1|Cu-oxidase' $e
then
    echo xyz >$e.match.txt
else
    echo
fi

if grep -q -E 'AMO' $e
then
    echo abc >$e.match.txt
else
    echo
fi; done
```

Any comments on that? It seems inefficient to grep twice, but it works...