# Compare string variables in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I tried

```
if [ "$str1" == "$str2" && "$str3" == "$str4" ];
then
  statement
else
   statement
fi
```

I've tried with one equal sign.  I've tried with two equal signs.  I've tried with and without quotation marks.  I've tried without the semi-colon.  Nothing seems to work.

I keep getting error

```
[: missing `]'
```

I have not the slightest clue on what that means.  I've tried my function with out this if statement and it works. PEOPLE I HAVE A SPACE between the leading and trailing brackets.

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate of the wrong thing - this addresses "and" for two tests http://stackoverflow.com/a/8920266/478656  (but the other suggestion that you need a space before ] still holds).

Comment: pay attention to the space in the beginning and ending of the []

Comment: what if you have all the spaces between brackets?  Is there another reason this might not work?  Will nesting if statements work?

Comment: @Wilson, keep cool man. For such testing you must use `[[ ... && ... ]]` in your source. Then you can get great debug info by pasting your source in http://www.shellcheck.net/ -- note that you must be sure of the shell you run on.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
s1="hi"
s2="hi"

if [ "$s1" == "$s2" ]
then
  echo match
fi
```

Provide spaces between square brackets and variables and you will get exact output.

**Updated for two comparisons:**

```
#!/bin/bash
str1="test"
str2="test"
str3="test"
str4="test"

if [ "$str1" = "$str2" ] && [ "$str3" = "$str4" ]
then
        echo "equals"
fi
exit 0;
```

Comment: are there any other ways this can be accomplished.  I had a question with all the ways I tried it but it was marked as dup.  This way does not work.

Comment: yes it works.Thank you huan feng