# How do I check whether a variable has an even numeric value?

Tags: bash

How should I change this to check whether `val` has an even or odd numeric value?

```
val=2
if $((RANDOM % $val)); ...
```

Comment: What do you want to check?

Comment: I need this to be a correct conditional statement to check whether the random variable is even. Now it just says: "0: command not found"

Comment: Like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash

Comment: I just don't quite understand what am I doing wrong and what is the correct syntax. Square brackets around don't help either.

Comment: `if [ $(( $RANDOM  % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then echo "even" ; fi` can work

Comment: Oh, I got it, should have left spaces around square brackets.

Comment: I believe the question here is - "Is the number even and not odd?"  The answers here reflect this.  There may be other questions that answer this.  But the link used to mark the question duplicate is incorrect.  That question answers if the variable is set.

Comment: @Anthon the duplicate link is not related

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate of the question marked as a duplicate! *That* question regards whether a variable has had a value assigned to it (or if it exists), *this* question regards whether the numeric value of a variable is an even or odd number.

I haven't checked the edits, but maybe the questioner clarified the question after first posting it?

How do I mark something as falsely flagged?

Answer (score 68):

```
$ a=4

$ [ $((a%2)) -eq 0 ] && echo "even"
even

$ a=3

$ [ $((a%2)) -eq 0 ] && echo "even"
```

Answer (score 48):

```
foo=6

if [ $((foo%2)) -eq 0 ];
then
    echo "even";
else
    echo "odd";
fi
```

Answer (score 13):

`$(( ... ))` is just an expression. Its result appears where `bash` expects a command.

A POSIX-compatible solution would be:

```
if [ "$(( RANDOM % 2))" -ne 0 ];
```

but since `RANDOM` isn't defined in POSIX either, you may as well use the right `bash` command for the job: an arithmetic evaluation compound command:

```
if (( RANDOM % 2 )); then
```

Comment: it is weird (ie, hard to read) that the `if (( RANDOM % 2 )); then` will be true when RANDOM is NOT a multiple of 2 ...

Comment: This is the same idiom commonly used in other languages. C would have `if ( random/2 ) { ... }`. Python would have `if random/2: ...`.