# Bash: How to set a variable from argument, and with a default value

Tags: bash, shell, unix

It is pretty clear that with shell scripting this sort of thing can be accomplished in a huge number of ways (more than most programming languages) because of all the different variable expansion methods and programs like `test` and `[` and `[[`, etc.

Right now I'm just looking for

```
DIR=$1 or .
```

Meaning, my DIR variable should contain either what is specified in the first arg or the current directory.

What is the difference between this and `DIR=${1-.}`?

I find the hyphen syntax confusing, and seek more readable syntax.

Why can't I do this?

```
DIR="$1" || '.'
```

I'm guessing this means "if $1 is empty, the assignment still works (DIR becomes empty), so the invalid command '.' never gets executed."

Comment: I found my answer to what the colon means: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value

Comment: Embrace the language. Not all languages have the same idioms. `DIR=${1:-.}` is a perfectly natural way to express this logic in any POSIX-compatible shell.

Comment: I find the downvote to be entirely justified. I don't like the way I wrote this question. I was frustrated at the time, I guess. But ever since I posted this, I've never had any trouble remembering the `${VAR:-default}` syntax. I'm going to edit my question to make it less petty. I'm sure you weren't the downvoter @chepner but you are absolutely right!

Comment: I never downvoted (or if I did, I subsequently retracted it).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I see several questions here.

1. “Can I write something that actually reflects this logic”

   Yes.  There are a few ways you can do it.  Here's one:

   ```
   if [[ "$1" != "" ]]; then
       DIR="$1"
   else
       DIR=.
   fi
   ```
2. “What is the difference between this and `DIR=${1-.}`?”

   The syntax `${1-.}` expands to `.` if `$1` is unset, but expands like `$1` if `$1` is set—even if `$1` is set to the empty string.

   The syntax `${1:-.}` expands to `.` if `$1` is unset or is set to the empty string.  It expands like `$1` only if `$1` is set to something other than the empty string.
3. “Why can't I do this?  `DIR="$1" || '.'`”

   Because this is bash, not perl or ruby or some other language.  (Pardon my snideness.)

   In bash, `||` separates entire commands (technically it separates pipelines).  It doesn't separate expressions.

   So `DIR="$1" || '.'` means “execute `DIR="$1"`, and if that exits with a non-zero exit code, execute `'.'`”.

Comment: just a nitpick. Your first example won't work under `set -u`, when no argument is given. Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/18448624/1190453 is a better example.

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
DIR=.
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
  DIR=$1
fi
```

`$#` is the number of arguments given to the script, and `-gt` means "greater than", so you basically set `DIR` to the default value, and if the user has specified an argument, then you set `DIR` to that instead.

Comment: This is not horrible, though four lines definitely seems too verbose for my liking. I'd rather just use the hyphen var-expansion since I already know what it means at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I use a simple helper function to make such assignments look cleaner. The function below accepts any number of arguments, but returns the first one that's not the empty string.

```
default_value() {
    # Return the first non-empty argument
    while [[ "$1" == "" ]] && [[ "$#" -gt "0" ]]; do
        shift
    done
    echo $1
}
x=$(default_value "$1" 0)
```