# Echo into var (shell)

Tags: shell

I have to verify that a var exist, if it does, it has to put a phrase like : "hello how are you" into a variable.

i tried :

```
test -e cours_420216
if [ $? ]
echo "alrdy there"
else
echo "add this into" > cours_420216
```

Comment: for a bash-solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

Variable assignment in bash is done in the form:

`cours_420216="hello how are you"`

`echo "add this into" > cours_420216`

would create a file and not assign a variable