# Test if two variable are empty at the same time

Tags: bash, variables, conditional-operator

I would like to test both variable in the same if condition.

Currently I am using [[ $var ]] to test one but the same for two variable do not work.

In order to do that I tried :

```
if [[ &var1 && &var2 ]]; then
or 
if [[ &ipAddress ]] && [[ &bcastAddress ]]; then
```

Is there a limitation ?

Comment: Why do you have `&` before the variables instead of `$`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this combined test:

```
[[ -z "${var1}${var2}" ]]
```

OR separate tests in same `if` condition:

```
[[ -z "$var1" && -z "$var2" ]]
```

Comment: No need for double quotes in `[[ .. ]]`.

Comment: Yes that is true but it doesn't cause any adverse affect also. IMO habit of quoting in BASH should be maintained as much as possible :)

Answer (score 1):

I often use arithmetic for these sorts of things. For example:

```
case "$(((!${#var1}&&!${#var2})*${#ip}))" in 
(0) ! echo ERROR;; 
(${#bcast}) echo '$ips len is equal to $bcasts and neither are zero';;
esac
```

Of course, you don't need the `case` there:

```
[ "${#var1}${#var2}" -eq "$(((${#ip}&&${#bcast})?0:-1))" ] || handle_it
```