# check dynamic variable name exist in bash

Tags: bash

I wish got message "missing global variable varB".

```
 chk_var() {
   local n v
   for n in varA varB varC; do
     eval v=\$$n test -n "$v" && [[ -n $v ]] \
       || echo "Err: missing global variable \$$n"
   done
 }
varA=3
varB=4
chk_var
```

Answer (score 9):

```
chk_var() {
   local n v 
   for n in varA varB varC; do
       if [ -z ${!n+x} ]; then 
           echo "$n is unset"; 
       else 
           echo "$n is set to '${!n}'"; 
       fi
   done
 }
varA=3
varB=4
chk_var
```

see: [How to check if a variable is set in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash)

the `!` before `n` in `${!n+x}` and `${!n}` is for indirect access.

*Gives:*

```
varA is set to '3'
varB is set to '4'
varC is unset
```