# What does the '-' (dash) after variable names do here?

Tags: linux, bash

```
if [ -n "${BASH-}" -o -n "${ZSH_VERSION-}" ] ; then
    hash -r 2>/dev/null
fi
```

Where can I find the reference on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Variables inside a `${...}` are called « Parameter Expansion ».
Search for that term [in the online manual](https://man.cx/bash#heading14), or the actual manual (line 792).
The `${var-}` form is similar in form to `${var:-}`. The difference is explained just one line before the `:-` expansion (line 810):

> ... bash tests for a parameter that is unset or null. Omitting the colon
>   results in a test only for a parameter that is unset.

Thus, this form is testing only when a variable is unset (**and** not null), and replaces the whole expansion `${...}` for the value after the `-`, which in this case is **null**.

Therefore, the `${var-}` becomes:

1. The value of var when var has a value (and not null).
2. Also the value of var (the colon : is missing!) when var is null:`''`, thus: also null.
3. The value after the - (in this case, null `''`) if var is unset.

All that is just really:

1. Expand to `''` when var is either unset or null.
2. Expand to the value of the var (when var has a value).

Therefore, the expansion changes nothing about the value of var, nor it's expansion, just avoids a possible error if the shell has the option `nounset` set.

This code will stop on both uses of `$var`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -u

unset var

echo "variable $var"
[[ $var ]] && echo "var set"
```

However this code will run without error:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -u

unset var
echo "variable ${var-}"
[[ ${var-} ]] && echo "var set"
```

Answer (score 5):

Its a bash parameter expansion thats used for checking if a variable is not set

#### Explanation

When you use `${ZSH_VERSION-WORD}` as opposed to `$ZSH_VERSION` in your bash script, bash will perform additional logic

```
if $ZSH_VERSION is set
then 
    simply use the value of $ZSH_VERSION as per normal

elseif

$ZSH_VERSION is NOT set 
then
    use value of WORD - which isnt provided in your case - so null
```

is used

#### References

Basic parameter expansion is covered in the `man bash` docs
(line 939 of bash man page).

see: [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)

also see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16753536/4668401)

Comment: It is covered in the [Bash Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions), as BinaryZebra correctly points out in his answer.

Comment: thanks @Ben Voigt have removed incorrects parts of my answer. I agree binary zebras answer gives better explanation

Answer (score 3):

Under normal circumstances, `${FOO-}` behaves exactly the same as `${FOO}`.

However, with `set -u`, expansion of unset variables becomes an error by default.

So `${FOO}` could be an error, but `${FOO-}` never will be.

Comment: You never say what the `-` actually means. It's not an error suppression operator.