# Where is ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-} being set

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, environment-variables, visual-studio-mac

When creating a new ASP.NET Core 3 project in Visual Studio for Mac, and then right clicking the project and selecting Add - Docker Support, IDE add docker-compose project to the solution and scaffolds the dockerfile for the API project.

docker-compose has the following entry by default:

```yaml
services:
  project-name:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}projectname
  ...
```

It works out of the box, dockerfile gets processed, compose is called, all good. But what entity during the "compose up + debug" process defines the value for DOCKER_REGISTRY variable?

Comment: I think from the image section in your compose file

Comment: seems like it set the docker default registry. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/147

Answer (score 11):

It is an environment var on your pc or remote server, try to type :

```
$ echo $DOCKER_REGISTRY
```

the docker entry means "If variable DOCKER_REGISTRY is not set or null, use default", then it is prepended to your project name.

See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02 for parameters expansion

Comment: I think this isn't quite correct. `${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}` will only test for a value of `DOCKER_REGISTRY` not being set, and will not test if it's null, according to this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32675207/1549918. So in theory, the default value for `DOCKER_REGISTRY` will only be used if the environment variable isn't set.

Comment: See also: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#interpolation

Comment: The link for parameter expansion is helpful

Answer (score 9):

From the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#interpolation

> ${VARIABLE-default} evaluates to default only if VARIABLE is unset in the environment.

In the case of your generated file `${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}projectname`

- If DOCKER_REGISTRY is set, say to "docker.io/"

  - The image name would be "docker.io/projectname"
- If DOCKER_REGISTRY is NOT set

  - The image name would be "projectname"

    - This shorthand name, also defaults to docker registry so you won't see difference unless you set DOCKER_REGISTRY to something other than the default registry.

> what entity during the "compose up + debug" process defines the value for DOCKER_REGISTRY variable?

I don't think it is defining a value for the variable. It is setting your compose file to SUPPORT the setting of using DOCKER_REGISTRY to consistently control same registry for all images used.