What does a trailing dash do in a parameter expansion?
I have this code:
if [[ ! -z "${ENV_OVERRIDE-}" ]]; then
    CFG="some/path/$ENV_OVERRIDE.conf"
fi

It seems to be doing the same thing without the trailing dash/hyphen as well:
if [[ ! -z "${ENV_OVERRIDE}" ]]; then
    CFG="some/path/$ENV_OVERRIDE.conf"
fi

What does the trailing dash do after all?

Found the answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/735031/201820

Did a google search before posting. The suggestions made by Stack Overflow when I tried to post the new question didn't help at all. Looks like this hasn't been asked on Stack Overflow.

It took a few tries, but I found the duplicate with the search [bash] title:hyphen title:variable answers:1

And I got a second duplicate using title:dash instead of title:hyphen.

The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32675207/6862601 has everything you need.

There is another question which seems most original: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10390406/6862601

Parameter expansion. Brace expansion is an entirely different thing.

The dash in ${ENV_OVERRIDE-} is used to provide a default value. If ENV_OVERRIDE is unset then it takes the value that you write after.
For example here:
echo ${ENV_OVERRIDE-my_value}

If ENV_OVERRIDE was unset, it would be assigned to my_value. The reason why both of your codes are equivalent is because the default is an empty string.

You may want to reference the more comprehensive answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32675207/6862601
