# Break for loop if variable is false

Tags: unix, if-statement, for-loop, sh

Trying to break a for loop if the variable $DEVP doesn't exist.

```
nme=(Y6T1 Y6-T1 Y6.T1 Yr6T1 Yr6-T1 Yr6.T1 Yr6Term1)
DEVP=(/dev/disk2 /dev/disk3 /dev/disk4 /dev/disk5 /dev/disk6 /dev/disk7 /dev/disk8)

for ((i = 0; i < 7; i++)) ; do 
    if [ ${nme[i]} ${DEVP[i]} = 0 ] ; then
        diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 ${nme[i]} ${DEVP[i]}
    else
        echo “Formatted USBs” ; break
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The break works fine

```
for ((i = 0; i < 7; i++)) ; do
    if [ $i -lt 3 ] ; then
       echo $i
    else            
        echo “Formatted USBs” ; break
    fi
done
```

Output is:

```
0
1
2
“Formatted USBs”
```

, however I'm not sure regarding your `if` statement, you should probably use `-z`.

```
 if [ -z ${DEVP[i]} ] ; then
```

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash)

Comment: I tried -z but then realised that it should be -d instead. I have just run the if loop but it's returns false when I search for the directory. It doesn't seem to recognise directories that exist?

Comment: Are you sure it's a directory? You need -b for the block device

Comment: I just ran ls and noticed it was a Block device. I didn't know you could use -b. Thank you, Roman. Legend!

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison looks like you expect the two strings to contain the single number zero.  They never will.  If they are empty, they will contain the empty string. (But even then having two string arguments to the left of the comparison operator is a syntax error.)

Anyway, if the actual problem you are trying to solve is that you don't know how many elements these arrays contain, just ask.

```
for((i=0; i<${#DEVP[@]}; ++i)); do
```

Of course, if the arrays contain a different number of arguments, you could still end up in a situation where `${nme[i]}` is undefined.

```
    ${nme[i]+:} break
```

This is rather obscure -- it will expand to the empty string before `break` (and thus break out of the loop) if the value is unset; if it's set, this is just a `:` noop.

Answer (score 0):

First repair the syntax: Put things in quotes in the if statement.

EDIT: I thought you needed to refer to the var `i` with `$i`, but @tripleee showed me, that this is optional in bash arrays. I removed the extra `$` characters.

```
nme=(Y6T1 Y6-T1 Y6.T1 Yr6T1 Yr6-T1 Yr6.T1 Yr6Term1)
DEVP=(/dev/disk2 /dev/disk3 /dev/disk4 /dev/disk5 /dev/disk6 /dev/disk7 /dev/disk8)
for ((i = 0; i < 7; i++)) ; do
        if [ "${nme[i]} ${DEVP[i]}" = 0 ] ; then
                echo "diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 ${nme[i]} ${DEVP[i]}"
        else
                echo “Formatted USBs” ; break
        fi
done
```

If you want to check the vars being empty, introduce an error by looping until 8.
I have put an echo in front of the diskutil line, so you can test without doing something you do not want.

```
for ((i = 0; i < 8; i++)) ; do
        if [ -z "${nme[i]}" ]; then
           echo "loop $i: \${nme[i]} is empty";
           break;
        fi
        if [ -z "${DEVP[i]}" ]; then
           echo "loop $i: \${DEVP[i]} is empty";
           break;
        fi
        echo "diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 ${nme[i]} ${DEVP[i]}"
done
```

Comment: The `$` is optional in array subscripts in Bash.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks, I usually try to avoid arrays in bash. Without the `$` the code looks cleaner!

Comment: There is still no way for `"${nme[i]} ${DEVP[i]}"` to ever be literally the string zero, so that part of the logic would need another round of thinking.  My guess is that the intent was to take the `if` branch if either (or both?) are unset but this is really just pure unadultered guesswork.  The question simply isn't very clear.

Comment: Sorry it should have been  `if [ -b ${DEVP[i]} ] ; then`. ${nme[i]} shouldn't of been in there. @Roman got it.