# What's the difference between ${var} and ${var-}

Tags: bash

I've seen some shell scripts that make use of this variable reference notation and I just can't find any info on it.

As far as my tests have gone it is just plainly the same.

Any clues?

```
$ uno=1
$ if [ -n "${uno}" ]; then echo yay\! ; fi
yay!
$ if [ -n "${uno-}" ]; then echo yay\! ; fi
yay!
```

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin for fixing my english punctuation

Comment: I didn't fix the punctuation, I removed a tag - all punctuation credit goes to @sphanley ;)

Comment: ok then. Thank you very much @sphanley !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Bash manual, about [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> `${parameter:-word}`
>
> If *parameter* is unset or null, the expansion of *word* is substituted. Otherwise, the value of *parameter* is substituted.

In your case, `word` is the empty string, and the colon is omitted. Without the colon, the check is just for unset, but not for null, so `${uno-}` is equivalent to checking if `uno` is set (see [How to check if a variable is set in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash)), and if it is not, expand it to the empty string – guaranteeing that the expansion is not unset.

It depends on the context what this is good for; in your example, it really makes no difference.

<sub>Turns out the context is a script where `set -u` is used – see [John 1024's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37306128/3266847) for the details.</sub>

Comment: Plus 1 for chasing down that the OP's code used `set -u` and why that was important.

Comment: @John1024 I've already +1ed your answer  - nice job consolidating the fragmented info!

Answer (score 7):

`${uno-}` is an example of providing a default value in case the parameter `uno` is unset.

If `uno` is unset, we get the string that follows the `-`:

```
$ unset uno
$ echo ${uno-something}
something
```

If `uno` is merely the empty string, then the value of `uno` is returned:

```
$ uno=""
$ echo ${uno-something}

$
```

If `uno` has a non-empty value, of course, then that value is returned:

```
$ uno=Yes
$ echo ${uno-something}
Yes
```

#### Why use `${variable-}`?

When proper operation of a script is important, it is common for the script writer to use `set -u` which generates an error message anytime an unset variable is used.  For example:

```
$ set -u
$ unset uno
$ echo ${uno}
bash: uno: unbound variable
```

To handle the special cases where one may want to suppress this message, the trailing `-` can be used:

```
$ echo ${uno-}

$
```

[Credit for finding that the OP's [full code](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-lb/blob/master/run) used `set -u` and its importance to this question goes to Benjamin W.]

#### Documentation

From `man bash`

> When not performing substring expansion, using the forms documented
>   below (e.g., :-), bash tests for a parameter that is unset or null. 
>   **Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is
>   unset.**
>   ${parameter:-word}
>  **Use Default Values**.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value
>   of parameter is substituted. [emphasis added]

Comment: Take a closer look, that has a colon in it's syntax so it's not the same

Comment: @olopopo The colon is addressed in the quote from the manual.

Comment: Ok, that bold text made me realize. Thanks and sorry for my obfuscation!

Comment: @BenjaminW. so in the case of just referring to the variable as ${uno-} doesn't make any difference. That was my question in the first place BTW

Comment: @olopopo It makes a difference if `uno` is unset.

Comment: @BenjaminW. hmmm sorry but I guess in this particular case it does not apply:
`unset uno ; if [ -n "${uno}" ]; then echo yay\! ; fi ; if [ -n "${uno-}" ]; then echo yay\! ; fi`

Comment: You can take a look at the script if you like [https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-lb/blob/master/run]

Comment: @olopopo Ah. The important point there is `set -u` ("treat unset variables as an error when substituting"). Try this: `set -u; unset var` and then `[[ -n ${var-} ]]` vs `[[ -n ${var} ]]`.