# Checking if the first argument passed to a bash script is set?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm attempting to see whether the first argument passed to my script is set.  I used the instructions found here to create a test:
[How to check if a variable is set in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash)

Here's my script:

```
var=$1
if [ -z ${var+x} ]; then echo "var is unset"; else echo "var is set to '$var'"; fi
```

Suppose I run it without any arguments:

```
ole@MKI:./test.sh
var is set to ''
```

Suppose I run it with an argument:

```
ole@MKI:./test.sh foo
var is set to 'foo'
```

In neither case does it report that the var is unset.

Thoughts?

TIA,
Ole

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
var=$1
```

This sets `var` and it does so regardless of whether `$1` is set or not.  The solution is to test `$1`:

```
if [ -z ${1+x} ]; then echo "var is unset"; else echo "var is set to '$1'"; fi
```

This approach works:

```
$ test.sh
var is unset
$ test.sh a
var is set to 'a'
```

Answer (score 3):

Even if no parameter is provided when the script is run, the `var` variable is set. It is assigned the empty string.

The shell also set the `$#` special parameter to the number of parameters.

Give a try to this:

```
if [[ $# = 0 ]] ; then printf "no parameter\n"; exit 1; else printf "At least one parameter\n"; var="${1}"; fi
```

If you go ahead with other additional parameters such as options, then you may consider to use the [getopts - parse utility options -](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html) from **The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7**