# Short way to run command if variable is set

Tags: bash

This is a hack I just discovered:

```
DEBUG=true
$DEBUG && echo "Hello"
```

And this just happens to work because `true` is an actual command which returns 0, and the `&&` operator is happy with that:

```
» true
» echo $?
0
```

Is there a non-hackish way of execute a piece of code if a variable is set, to *whatever value*, except the empty string? Something like this, but as a *readable* one-liner (like the one above):

```
myvar="ggg"
if [ "$myvar" != "" ] ; then echo "Hello" ; fi
```

Comment: `[[ -n "$myvar" ]] && echo "Hello"` should work

Comment: `[ -z ${myvar+x} ] && echo "Hello"` [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bashsee)

Comment: I don't think it is hackish.

Comment: @hek2mgl: it relies on the shell executing the expansion of a variable as a command, which happens to return a true value. That seems quite hackish. And besides, it does not solve the *whatever value* part ...

Comment: I definitely agree that it's a hack. Personally, I use integer values: `foo=1; ((foo)) && whatever`, or check for empty strings: `[[ $foo ]] && whatever`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of relying on the value of the variable to have an executable value (and a value that you *want* to be executed), define a function that simply checks if the value is set.

```
debug () [[ -v DEBUG ]]

debug && echo "Hello"
```

If `DEBUG` is set *at all*, even to the empty string, `debug` will succeed and the following command executes.

If `DEBUG` is not set and you want your script to run the debug commands, simply invoke it as

```
DEBUG= ./myscript
```

If `DEBUG` is set, you can unset it first.

```
unset DEBUG
./myscript
```

---

If the value of `DEBUG` really matters for whatever reason, then you can just test that it has a non-empty value instead of using `-v`:

```
debug () [[ -n $DEBUG ]]
```

To run your script in debug mode, pick an arbitrary non-empty value

```
DEBUG=1 ./myscript
```

To run your script in "real" mode even if `DEBUG` is current set in your environment, use

```
DEBUG= ./myscript
```

Answer (score 22):

If you want to use the value:

```
[[ -n $DEBUG ]] && echo "Hello"
```

If you want to use the negation of the value:

```
[[ -z $DEBUG ]] && echo "Hello"
```

That's I think is the **shortest**. Note the `$` in front of the variable name is required.

Comment: Can you tell me where that syntax comes from? I'd like to be able to document and understand why this works [[ -n $DEBUG ]].

Comment: @LisaKester `man test` lists all the tests (`-n`, `-z`, etc.) that can be applied to an expression in your shell.