# Bash check environment var is set fails doesn't work

Tags: bash

just playing around on my server to get script the setup of the next server. Everything works - now I want to run it on the new server i got an error like this:

> sudo sh setup.sh 
>   Hostname is dinozzo
>   setup.sh: 10: setup.sh: [[: not found

The Script to start is not that much. 
Line 10 is

> if [[ "$INT_DEV_HOSTNAME" ]]; then

But I don't get it why it is not working on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

Comment: The question was already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash

Comment: `sh` is not the same as `bash`.  `[[` is a bash-ism -- so execute the script with `bash` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You explicetly tell the shell to use sh :

```
sudo sh setup.sh Hostname is dinozzo setup.sh: 10: setup.sh: [[: not found
```

In this mode, even if it's [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) that you are using by default, it will produce the error because it will be in *POSIX* mode.

`[[ ]]` form of `test` need to be called from within a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) shell (other shells support it too, like ksh, zsh...)