# How do I check if a variable is set in zsh?

Tags: zsh

What is the canonical / idiomatic way to test if a variable has been set in zsh?

```
if ....something.... ; then
    print "Sweet, that variable is defined"
else
    print "That variable is not defined"
fi
```

Here's [the SO answer for bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13864829/893113).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a variable is set in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash)

Comment: Huh. I mean, there *is* zsh-only syntax, but the POSIX sh syntax works here too.

Comment: Edited to clarify. The Bash question doesn't provide the canonical zsh syntax.

Comment: The linked question was asked (and mostly answered) before `bash` introduced the `-v` operator (which `zsh` also supports, see my answer).

Comment: I'm using OS X Sierra which ships with bash 3.2 and zsh 4.2, neither of which support `-v`.

Comment: The stock version of `bash` isn't really useful as anything other than a POSIX-compatible shell; it is *years* out of date. `/bin/zsh` should be 5.2 in OS X Sierra.

Comment: You're right, 5.2. That was a typo.

Answer (score 48):

The typical way to do this in Zsh is:

```
if (( ${+SOME_VARIABLE} )); then
```

For example:

```
if (( ${+commands[brew]} )); then
    brew install mypackage
else
    print "Please install Homebrew first."
fi
```

In Zsh 5.3 and later, you can use the `-v` operator in a conditional expression:

```
if [[ -v SOME_VARIABLE ]]; then
```

The POSIX-compliant test would be

```
if [ -n "${SOME_VARIABLE+1}" ]; then
```

Comment: @chepner Shouldn't that be `-n`, not `-z`?  `-z` is the inverse.

Comment: A portable way to check if a variable is set (even with null value): `isset() { [[ $(eval echo "\${${1}+1}") ]]; }`

Comment: If you're just manually checking, type `echo "${+SOME_VAR}"`

Answer (score 18):

Use the `-v` (introduced in `zsh` 5.3) operator in a conditional expression.

```
% unset foo
% [[ -v foo ]] && echo "foo is set"
% foo=
% [[ -v foo ]] && echo "foo is set"
foo is set
```

Comment: I know this is obvious, but just to emphasize that the $ shouldn't be put in front of the variable. I typed -v $foo just out of habit and spent ages trying to work out why it wasn't working, until I noticed I hadn't read the answer carefully and it should be -v foo !!!!

Comment: Indeed; `-v` takes a *name*, and if you provide a parameter expansion, it's the resulting value that's used as the name. (I'd hesitate to call anything in shell "obvious" :) )

Comment: well it wasn't obvious to me, but that's because, like most people these days, I do everything in a blinding hurry trying to do 7 things at the same time and thus don't read carefully, hence the reason I decided to post the comment ;-)