# How to test if a variable is set or not (empty strings count as set)

Tags: shell

I searched this site with Google for an answer that explains how to test if a variable is set or not in a shell (I'm using bash, but I'd prefer the solution to be portable) in the strictest sense of the word, but I failed to find any results.

The problem is that the common answers do not actually check to determine whether a variable is set or not. Instead, they check to see if it is empty or not. If I type `var=""`, then `var` is set to an empty string. Nonetheless, it has still been **set**. Running `[ -z "${var}" ]` will return `true` despite the variable existing.

How do I test if a variable is set or not across various shells as opposed to just empty or not?

Comment: Upon closer inspection, this looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash, I'll remove my (redundant) answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a variable is set in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash)

Comment: The top answer gives a POSIX sh way, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3601587/3266847) gives a Bash >= 4.2 way.

Comment: @BenjaminW., do you mean the one below that one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash/17538964#17538964