# Check if variables exist in a for loop in bash

Tags: bash

I need to check a lot of environment variables that need to be set in order for my bash script to run. I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash) and tried

```
thisVariableIsSet='123'

variables=(
  $thisVariableIsSet
  $thisVariableIsNotSet
)

echo "check with if"

# this works
if [[ -z ${thisVariableIsNotSet+x} ]]; then
  echo "var is unset";
else
  echo "var is set to '$thisVariableIsNotSet'";
fi

echo "check with for loop"

# this does not work
for variable in "${variables[@]}"
do
  if [[ -z ${variable+x} ]]; then
    echo "var is unset";
  else
    echo "var is set to '$variable'";
  fi
done
```

The output is:

```
mles:tmp mles$ ./test.sh 
check with if
var is unset
check with for loop
var is set to '123'
```

If I'm checking the not set variable in an if block, the check works (`var is unset`). However in the for loop the if block only prints if a variable is set, not if a variable ist not set.

How can I check variables in a for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use indirect expansion `${!var}`:

```
thisVariableIsSet='123'

variables=(
  thisVariableIsSet  # no $
  thisVariableIsNotSet
)

echo "check with if"

# this works
if [[ -z ${thisVariableIsNotSet+x} ]]; then
  echo "var is unset";
else
  echo "var is set to '$thisVariableIsNotSet'";
fi

echo "check with for loop"

# this does not work
for variable in "${variables[@]}"
do
  if [[ -z ${!variable+x} ]]; then   # indirect expansion here
    echo "var is unset";
  else
    echo "var is set to ${!variable}";
  fi
done
```

Output:

```
check with if
var is unset
check with for loop
var is set to 123
var is unset
```