# Pass a flag along with other arguments via command line to a ksh script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh, gnu

I am trying to write a ksh script that takes an optional flag and two mandatory strings as argument. The flag is denoted as `-a`. Thus the command look like one of the following when correct:

1. `command.sh -a -b abc -c 123`
2. `command.sh -b xyz -c 789`

I am using the following code in my script:

```
while getopts "a:b:c:" args
do
    case $args in

        a) # Flag
            flag=1
            ;;
        b) # str1
            str1=$OPTARG
            ;;
        c) # str2
            str2=$OPTARG
            ;;
        *) # usage
            echo "- - - - "
            exit 0
            ;;
    esac
done

if [[ -z $str1 || -z $str2 ]]
then
    echo "Incomplete arguments supplied\n"
    exit 1
fi

...
```

Doing so when I execute 1 (see above) it throws me the message `Incomplete arguments supplied` where as 2 (see above) is working fine.

Can anyone point out what is going wrong and recommend a rectification?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colon (`:`) after the option letter specifies that the option (aka flag) requires an argument; since you have a colon (`:`) after the 'a', `getopts` is expecting an argument to go along with `-a`; try this instead:

```
while getopts "ab:c:" args
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked... I think doing the following also be the same: `while getopts "b:c:a" args` (i.e, putting flag that needs no arguments at the end without a succeeding `:` to make it look more clean).

Answer (score 0):

-z option to check whether variable is set is  not used correctly. Refer to the below link for correct usage:
[How to check if a variable is set in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash)

Comment: I tried these changes, but still I get the same message: `Incomplete arguments supplied\n`