# What does ${VARIABLE+x} mean in bash?

Tags: bash, syntax

I've come across code that uses this syntax in an if condition:

```
if [ ! -z ${VARIABLE+x} ]; then
    some commands here
fi
```

Does it test for an non-empty variable? If so, how is it different from `! -z "$VARIABLE"`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13864829/214577

Comment: @Oldskool Do you mind posting that as an answer?

Comment: I would, as that would be plagiarism :-) I'm just saying that answer pretty much answers your question.

Answer (score 10):

See *PARAMETER EXPANSION* in `man bash`:

> `${parameter:+word}`
>
> Use Alternate Value.  If `parameter` is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise the expansion of `word` is substituted.

And few paragraphs above in the same section:

> Omitting the colon results in  a  test  only
>          for a parameter that is unset.