# How to pass enviornment variable to bash function for validation and get the string of the argument

Tags: bash

```
validate() {

        if [ -z "$1" ]
        then
                echo "$1 variable does not set !"
                exit 1
        else
                echo "$1 variable is set !"
        fi

}
```

the problem is that when the varibal not set the $1 dosn't evaluate to any thing and im getting empty string
how can i get the argument name string so i can pressent it

i call the function like this :

validate "$FOO"
**Edit**
My question is how to get in the function the argument  name not value 
So it give me the "$FOO" string
Im not asking how to validate the value
SO if $FOO does not set it will print me
$FOO variable does not set !

Comment: You are reinventing `: ${FOO?unset}`

Comment: Also, don't use uppercase for your private variables.

Comment: it not the same , im talking about handling the var in the function as argument

Comment: Several answers in the duplicate explain exactly how to do that.

Comment: not as the function argument, again im asking how to get the argument name not value

Comment: Are you positive you have read all the answers, in particular https://stackoverflow.com/a/17538964/874188?

Comment: yes im sure , this validate "$FOO" : 
give me : 
0 variable does not set !

i want it to be $FOO variable does not set !

Comment: Look. There is no way you can pass an undefined variable to a function. You can pass the label in which case `[[ -v "FOO" ]]` does exactly what you want. If you don't know how the shell works, take my word. You are wasting your own time and mine.

Comment: @user63898 The only solution I could find is to use variable indirection when calling your function, i.e. `validate ${!FOO@}`