# How to check if a variable is set in a string in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, variables

Let assume I have something like below:

```
eval link='/var/lib/${XYZ}/test' # string from another text file
```

XYZ is just for the the example and it could be anything like below:

```
eval link='/var/lib/${MY_OWN_VAR}/test' # single quote here not double quotes
eval link='/var/lib/${WHAT_EVER}/test'
```

Is it possible to error out if `XYZ` is not set? or is there any other way to figure out if `XYZ` is set or not?

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash), but the assumption there is that you know the variable name. In my case I have no control over what would be in the string to be evaluated.

**UPDATE**

To be clear, all the strings that needs to be evaluated are from a text file. basically a program reads a text file and 
 outputs the evaluated strings.

All I am trying here is to figure out a way to gracefully catch "unbound variable" error while evaluating any string. basically what `set -u` does but gracefully.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I looked at that,  and it doesn't fit my criteria.

Comment: There is `set -u` to complain if you use an undefined variable, but it comes with a few [caveats](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112).

Comment: @PMoubed Please share your code because it’s hard to know what you’re trying to do. Do you want to check any Bash file for unset variables? How can you use a variable in a string without having its name?

Comment: so...your question is that you assume a string may have a variable embedded, but you are getting it post-parse and the variable might not have had a value? Can you scan for //?

Comment: @PaulHodges you are right, but assume you may have it at any place in the string.

Comment: @BenjaminW I have tried set -u but is there a way to gracefully do this?

Comment: If you have a sting that might have had a value already parsed into it, but possibly an empty one, then no, there's no way to look at the string after the fact and see whether a variable that was embedded *somewhere* maybe had no value.

Comment: If you have access to the string *before* it parses you can use one of the parameter expansion modifiers, but after the fact, you're out of luck.

Comment: Why are you using `eval`?

Comment: "I have no control over what would be in the string to be evaluated."  This is a recipe for disaster.  Invoking `eval` on unknown content is perhaps the biggest possible error you will ever make.

Comment: Any other way without using eval then? If a program reads a text file that includes all strings that might have variables and outputs actual strings what would be the best way to catch if a variable is not set?

Comment: What do you mean by "outputs the evaluated strings"? The examples you have given are assignments to variable link which I wouldn't expect to produce any output.

Comment: @jhnc if XYZ is set to 'something' then the string will be evaluated to /var/lib/something/test

Comment: So, the file only contains the `'...'` part, not the assignment? Where are the variables set? In the text file, or somewhere else?

Comment: @jhnc in my case there are some logic before this which sources other files and the variable are from those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the eval in a subshell before performing it for real:

```
assign_if_defined(){
    echo 1>&2 "testing $1=$2"
    outvar="$1"
    input=${2@Q}
    err=$(exec 2>&1; set -u; eval "${outvar}=${input@P}")
    if [ -z "$err" ]; then
        echo 1>&2 "eval test succeeded: doing for real"
        eval "${outvar}=${input@P}"
    else
        echo 1>&2 "eval test failed: not doing for real"
        echo 1>&2 "error: $err"
    fi
}

A=set
assign_if_defined link1 "'"'"\/${A}/'
echo link1=$link1

unset B
assign_if_defined link2 '/$B/'
echo link2=$link2
```

It seems that the `@Q`/`@P` transformations first appeared in bash 4.4. Using them means that quoting is much simplified. If using an older version of bash, you could try normal quoting (`eval "${outvar}=\"${input}\""`) but the code will fail if `input` contains special characters (as the first example).

Comment: This is very helpfull; what is the purpose of exec 2>&1;?

Comment: What happens if you remove it?

Comment: also I am getting ${2@Q}: bad substitution, I tried bash and sh.

Comment: If I remove exec 2>&1; then err will be empty and error from eval printed out to screen

Comment: What OS and bash version? I'm using bash 4 on linux.

Comment: Exactly. So we need the exec redirection so that the error gets saved into the variable instead of being printed.

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release on Fedora 24

Comment: This is what I was looking for: `err=$(exec 2>&1; set -u; eval "${outvar}=${input@P}")`

Comment: Sorry, looks like `@Q`/`@P` may only have appeared in 4.4. I only used it to ensure that the code works even if special characters exist in the variable (as in the first example).

Comment: I accepted your response because it helped me solve my problem, but would you please update your code so it'll work an shell older than 4.4 for any other people come across this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know exactly how much control (or knowledge) you *do* have on the strings, but can't you just test if it's empty?

```
VAR=mydirectory
str=/var/lib/${VAR}/test             # valid
str2=/var/lib/${NONEXISTANT}/test    # invalid

if [[ "$str" = "/var/lib//test" ]] ;
then
    echo 'is_empty';
else
    echo 'is_set';
fi;
```

The only downfall is that the test will fail if you receive a var that is set but empty, e.g. `VAR=""`

Comment: I was hoping there would be a flag for eval to catch the error. This won't work for me. let's assume all the strings are from a text file.