# How to iterate over array to check list environment variables using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a bash script that runs a check to determine if the requisite environment variables are set before executing its logic.

At the moment I'm repeating the following code block for every environment variable:

```
if [[ -z "$SOME_ENV_VAR" ]]; then
    echo "Warning - the SOME_ENV_VAR environment variable isn't set"

    exit 1
fi
```

Is there a way to declare an array and iterate over the array and check if the environment variable is set?

I know how to iterate over arrays in bash, but I'm not sure how to use each iteration variable to 
check if a similarly named environment variable is present.

Comment: You can use pattern matching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use *indirection* to access a variable by its name if that name is stored in another variable. A small example:

```
x=1
name=x
echo "${!name}" # prints 1
```

With this approach, you only have to iterate over the names of the variables you want to check:

```
for name in FIRST_ENV_VAR SECOND_ENV_VAR ...; do
    if [[ -z "${!name}" ]]; then
        echo "Variable $name not set!"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

You may also want to use `-z "${!name+x}"` to accept variables that are set to the empty string, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13864829/6770384).

Answer (score 3):

```
x=(
  LANG
  LC_MEASUREMENT
  LC_PAPER
  LC_MONETARY
  LC_NAME
  LC_ADDRESS
  LC_NUMERIC
  LC_TELEPHONE
  LC_IDENTIFICATION
  LC_TIME
)
for v in "${x[@]}"; do
  echo "$v = \"${!v}\""
done
```

Result:

```
LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC = "en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME = "en_US.UTF-8"
```

See the `bash`(1) [manual page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#expansion) for an explanation of indirect expansion using `${!`*name*`}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the list of the environment variables you want to iterate over as done in `ENV_VAR_ARR`.
 Then iterate over each of them using a `for` loop.

The for loop will take each item in the list, assigns it `SOME_ENV_VAR` and execute the commands between do and done then go back to the top, grab the next item in the list and repeat over.

The list is defined as a series of strings, separated by spaces.

```
#!/bin/bash

ENV_VAR_ARR='ENV_1 ENV_2 ENV_3'

for SOME_ENV_VAR in $ENV_VAR_ARR
do
    echo $SOME_ENV_VAR
    if [[ -z "${!SOME_ENV_VAR}" ]]; then
        echo "Warning - the $SOME_ENV_VAR environment variable isn't set"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```