# Check if an associative array exists

Tags: bash

Since [`bash` 4.2](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/CHANGES#L2792), the `-v` conditional expression has been added. It's used to check if a variable is set (has been assigned a value). It's a useful tool when writing scripts that run under `set -o nounset`, because attempting to use a non-initialized variable causes an error.

I have one issue with it, see the sample in a POSIX `bash` (`set -o posix`):

```
$ declare testvar=0
$ [ -v testvar ] && echo "It works!"
It works!
$ declare -A fizz=( [buzz]=jazz )
$ [ -v fizz[buzz] ] && echo "It works!"
It works!
$ [ -v fizz ] && echo "It doesn't work :("
$
```

As you can see, using `-v` on a regular variable works as expected. Using it to check the presence of a field within an associative array works as expected as well. However, when checking the presence of the associative array itself, it doesn't work.

Why is that, and is there a workaround?

Comment: Can't you still use `[ -z ${var+x} ]` even for `[ -z ${fizz[buzz]+x} ]` like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash)?

Comment: Weird. When you populate `fizz[0]`, `-v fizz` works. It somewhat makes sense though, since bare array name (fizz) is equivalent to fizz[0] during expansion

Comment: @oguzismail: Uh, you're right. This is very strange but this *feature* might be okay as a work-around :)

Comment: After further testing it seems that it only works if a `0` key is present. Which makes think that maybe, under the hood, it's not intended to be used on associative arrays: it checks for the presence of the 0th element.

Comment: Probably. I'll wait for someone with more knowledge to post a comprehensive explanation here anyways

Comment: Take a look at `declare -p fizz` as well, I guess it could be of use

Comment: Test if `fizz` is declared as an associative array, regardless of existing entries: `[[ "$(typeset -p fizz 2>&1)" =~ ^declare\ -A ]] && echo 'ok'`

Comment: @oguzismail: `declare -p` is a good suggestion, still feels a bit hack-ish but less that the `0`-key workaround :) If you post it as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: I think it's worth reporting as a bug, or at least a feature request. `$foo` expanding as `${foo[0]}` makes some sense with regard to POSIX compatibility, but with `-v` already being undefined by POSIX, there's no need for `foo` and `foo[0]` to be treated the same.

Comment: Note that `[ -v fizz[buzz] ]` wasn't supported until 4.4 as well, and in a very real sense `fizz` is not defined in the absence of a key. Arrays aren't distinct entities, just syntactic "magic" to support indexing.

Comment: @chepner Wrt *Arrays aren't distinct entities, just syntactic "magic" to support indexing.* that sounds correct based on the behavior, but the maual says *An array variable is considered set if a subscript has been assigned a value.*. I think this is a bit misleading, it bears in the mind that `-v` unary can be used on bare array names

Comment: @oguzismail Not really (unless this is a bug): try `-v` with `arr` after `declare -a arr=([1]=3)`. `-v` really does seem to be testing for index 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if it has any entries, you can check `${#fizz[@]}`, but that doesn't tell you if it has been created empty. You *can* use a case statement or other pattern matching in conjunction with error checking.

```
tst() { local tst;   
  (( $# )) || return                             # *minimal* error handling...
  if tst="$(declare -p $1 2>&1)"                 # does the subshell error?
  then case "$tst" in                            # if not, check the output
       *\)*) (( $( eval echo \${#$1[@]} ) )) &&  # test number of entries
                echo "Has Args"              ||  # some implementations show '()'
                echo "Empty but defined";;       # some don't; this is for the *do*
       *-A*) echo "Empty but defined";;          # this is for the don't
          *) echo ERROR;;                        # shouldn't get here
       esac
  else echo Undefined                            # if doesn't exist
  fi
}


$: unset fizz
$: tst fizz
Undefined
$: declare -A fizz
$: tst fizz
Empty but defined
$: fizz[buzz]=jazz
$: tst fizz
Has Args
```

Dunno how useful that will be in your context though.
Note that I wrote this one explicitly for associative arrays with minimal error checking not directly related to the point. For any sort of real production use this should be expanded a lot.

I don't like the `eval`, but my bash version doesn't have namerefs. :o/

Comment: I was really hoping for a simple way to use `${!fizz*}` or `${fizz?blah}` but nothing seems to be working the way I'd've hoped for this specific case of the difference between an empty associative array and an unset one...

Comment: Using `declare -p <var>` is a nice idea. Thanks for your input.

Comment: [oguz ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248678/oguz-ismail) suggested it above. I just expanded it out, lol

Answer (score 0):

## Strictly check is *varname* exist as an associative array:

```
check4Associative() {
    local foo typ
    read foo typ foo < <(declare -p $1 2>&1)
    [ "$typ" ] && [ -z "${typ//-*A*}" ]
}
```

You could use as:

```
if check4Associative myVar; then ... ;fi
```

Sample tries:

```
unset fizz
check4Associative fizz && echo yes;echo $?
1

fizz=Blah
check4Associative fizz && echo yes;echo $?
1

declare -A fizz
check4Associative fizz && echo yes;echo $?
yes
0

fizz[foo]=bar
check4Associative fizz && echo yes;echo $?
yes
0
```

### One step further: entry count:

```
check4AssociativeArgs() {
    local -n var=$1
    local keys=(${!var[@]}) foo typ
    read foo typ foo < <(declare -p $1 2>&1)
    [ "$typ" ] && [ -z "${typ//-*A*}" ] &&
        printf "Name: %s, type: %s, entry count: %d\n" $1 ${typ#-} ${#keys[@]}
}
```

Then

```
unset fizz
check4AssociativeArgs fizz ; echo $?
1

declare -A fizz
check4AssociativeArgs fizz
Name: fizz, type: A, entry count: 0

fizz[foo]=bar fizz[bar]=baz
check4AssociativeArgs fizz
Name: fizz, type: A, entry count: 2
```

Comment: I guess OP looks for an idiomatic way, which simply doesn't exist :/

Comment: @oguzismail Yes nice! As OP ask for *workaround*, I think you may post this!