# Gitlab CI: Fail pipeline if variable not set?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Is there a way fail my entire pipeline if the user triggered the pipeline and didn't set a variable called `options` with a value?

I've tried things like only and rules but they just skip the job instead of failing all jobs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, though the way you fail would be dependent on the system your runner's based on.

For example, in a Linux/bash based runner, all you need is `exit 1` (as opposed to `exit 0`) to stop execution and fail the pipeline

Comment: Thanks I've given it a try but I can't get the pipeline to exit am I doing something wrong with this if in my script section?   `script:
    - if [$options == null]; then exit 1; fi` The next line echos out options so I can see it's null but the if didn't exit

Comment: $options doesn't have default value if not set? you should use it in if condition instead of null

Comment: Yep, MoonHorse hit the nail on the head here. Just do use `if [ -z $options];` to make it a condition that checks if it's either unset, or null. 

This StackOverflow [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash) has a good summary of the different sorts of checks you could use here, but the approach above looks to be the best bet if you're looking to catch cases where the variable is unset or null.

Answer (score 0):

Testing the `options` environment variable in the script is one possibility. Another is to use the `options` variable to include (or exclude) a "killer" job from the pipeline. For example:

```yaml
verify-options-set:
  stage: .pre
  image: node:20
  tags:
    - linux-docker
  rules:
    - if: '$options == null'
  script:
    - echo "Define "options" to run the pipeline!"
    - exit 1
```

If the `options` environment variable is not set, this job (which *always* fails) is included in the pipeline. If it is set, the job is ignored.