# Bash: [[ -v xxx ]] test failed in login shell

Tags: bash

When I run the code below:

```
if [[ -v xxx ]]; then
    echo "OK"
fi
```

Error happens:

```
-bash: conditional binary operator expected
-bash: syntax error near `xxx'
```

It happens in the login shell.
When I run

```
bash
```

in the same login shell, then run the code above, the error disappears.

The OS is macOs Catalina, shell login command is

```
login -pf <username> /bin/bash
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Show your code. No xxx.

Comment: 'xxx' is the variable name I used when testing. It also happens when source bash_completion script. ```-bash: /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: line 251: conditional binary operator expected
-bash: /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: line 251: syntax error near `exclude'
-bash: /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: line 251: `    if [[ -v exclude ]]; then'
```

Comment: The question is why the error happens and how to fix or avoid it.

Comment: Your code works fine in my Bash.

Comment: Are you sure the error you you're getting pertains exactly to the code snippet you're showing? Perhaps show some context in your script that has the error.

Comment: More information: It's on macOS, in the login shell opened with command 'login -pf <username> /bin/bash'

Comment: `-v` is an operator. The error implies that operator isn't present, and that the code you're running isn't really identical to that given in the question.

Comment: That said... where I'd start is putting `set -x` earlier in your script to trace its execution, and editing that trace into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `login -pf <username> /bin/bash` on MacOS Catalina will put you into `bash` version 3.2.57(1).

In this version of `bash`, `-v` is not a valid operator for `[[ ]]`.

You likely normally use a more updated version of `bash`.  Try `echo $BASH_VERSION` while running each shell.

See this relevant SO question, [How to check if a variable is set in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash), where it is discussed that the `-v` option was available in version 4.2.

Comment: Thank you! The login bash version is 3.2.57, and the bash i usually use is 5.0.18, installed by homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

For bash in v3, install bash_completion, for bash in v4.2 and above, install bash_completion@2. If you have upgraded the bash on your mac, please make sure you update your default bash to the newer one, check [this link](https://itnext.io/upgrading-bash-on-macos-7138bd1066ba) for the steps.