# Converting a BASH script to run on SH (via BusyBox)

Tags: bash, sh, parameter-expansion

I have an Asus router running a recent version of [FreshTomato](https://freshtomato.org/) - that comes with BusyBox.

I need to run a script that was made with BASH in mind - it is an adaptation of [this script](https://github.com/coldfix/openvpn-routing-examples/blob/master/netns/move/update-resolv-conf) - but it fails to run with this error:  `line 41: syntax error: bad substitution`

Checking the script with [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) yields these errors:

```
Line 41:
        for optionvarname in ${!foreign_option_*} ; do
                             ^-- SC3053: In POSIX sh, indirect expansion is undefined.
                             ^-- SC3056: In POSIX sh, name matching prefixes are undefined.
 
Line 42:
        option="${!optionvarname}"
                ^-- SC3053: In POSIX sh, indirect expansion is undefined.
```

These are the lines that are causing problems:

```sh
for optionvarname in ${!foreign_option_*} ; do   # line 41
    option="${!optionvarname}"                   # line 42

    # do some stuff with $option...
done
```

If my understanding is correct, the original script simply does something with all variables that have a name starting with `foreign_option_`

However, as far as I could determine, both `${!foreign_option_*}` and `${!optionvarname}` constructs are BASH-specific and not POSIX compliant, so there is no direct "bash to sh" code conversion possible.

I have tried to create a `/bin/bash` symlink that points to `busybox`, but I got the `Read-only file system` error.

So, how can I get this script to run on my router? I see only two options, but I cant figure out how to implement either:

1. Make BusyBox interpret the script as BASH instead of SH - can I use a specific shebang for this?

   - Seems like the fastest option, but only if BusyBox has a "complete" implementation of BASH
2. Alter the script code to not use BASH specifics.

   - This is safer, but since there is no "collect al variables starting with X" for SH, how can I do it?

Comment: How about `set | grep -e "^X"` to collect variable names starting with `X`?

Comment: `sh` does NOT provide variable indirection such as `${!optionvarname}` which tries to evaluate the variable whose name is stored in `optionvarname`. That is a bash-only feature that results in "Bad Substitution"... Note your error message `"In POSIX sh, indirect expansion is undefined."` -- that is what that is telling you...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I figured out the issue, but sadly I am not that versed in `bash`/`sh` differences and intricacies in order to be able to do a proper conversion, hence the request for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I get this script to run on my router?

That easy, either:

- install bash on your router or
- port the script to busybox/posix compatible shell.

> Make BusyBox interpret the script as BASH instead of SH - can I use a specific shebang for this?

That doesn't make sense. Busybox comes with `ash` shell interpreter and bash is bash. Bash can interpret bash extensions, ash can't interpret them. You can't "make busybox interpret bash" - cars don't fly, planes are for that. If you want to make a car fly, you add wings to it and make it faster. The answer to `Make BusyBox interpret the script as BASH instead of SH` would be: patch busybox and implement all bash extensions in it.

Shebang is used to run a file under *different* interpreter. Using `#!/bin/bash` would invoke `bash`, which would be unrelated to anything busybox related and busybox wouldn't be involved in it.

> how can I do it?

Decide on a unrealistic maximum, iterate over variables named `foreign_option_{1...some_max}`, for each variable see if it is set, if it is set, cotinue the script.

```
for i in $(seq 100); do
    optionvarname="foreign_option_${i}"        
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash
    if eval "[ -z \"\${${optionvarname}+x}\" ]"; then continue; fi;
```

With enough *luck* maybe you can use the `set` output. The following will fail if any variable contains a value as newline + the string that matches the regex:

```
for optionvarname in $(set | grep -o '^foreign_option_[0-9]\+=' | sed 's/=//'); then
```

Indirect expansion can be easily replaced by `eval`:

```
eval "option=\"\$${optionvarname}\""
```

Comment: On my router, `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/busybox`. I will try the "unrealistic maximum" suggestion (not the `set` one), and I'll let you know how it went.

Answer (score 0):

If you really cannot install Bash on that router, here is one possible workaround, which seems to work for me in BusyBox on a Qnap NAS :

```
foreign_option_one=1
foreign_option_two=2

for x in one two; do
    opt_var=foreign_option_${x}
    eval "opt_value=\$$opt_var"
    echo "$opt_var = $opt_value"
done
```

(But you will probably encounter more problems with moving a Bash script to busybox, so you might want to first consider alternatives like replacing the router)