# Bash conditional expression (-v) to check if a variable is set

Tags: linux, bash, conditional-operator

When trying to check if a variable is set or unset in bash, I found the bash conditional expression: `-v` ([here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html): True if the shell variable is set (has been assigned a value).). I try the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR="not-empty"
if [ ! -v "$VAR" ]; then
        echo "unset"
else 
        echo "set: $VAR"
fi
```

But, the output is `unset` even i assigned `VAR` at the begin of code.

I found [How to check if a variable is set in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) question, and tried to replace `! -v` by `-z` to check the string variable `VAR`. The output is `set: non-empty`.

Anyone can help to explain the first case (using `-v` expression) why the output is `unset`?

My bash version:

> GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
> Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the manual for bash, I found:

```
   -v varname
          True if the shell variable varname is set (has been assigned a value).
```

But the problem is:

```
VAR="not-empty"
[ ! -v "$VAR" ]
```

is not incorrect, but performs a different test. It checks if there is a variable named 'not-empty' that is set.

You should test like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR="not-empty"
if [ ! -v VAR ]; then
        echo "unset"
else 
        echo "set: $VAR"
fi
```

Comment: This is a better answer, *except* that it's using `[` instead of `[[`. When you _absolutely require_ that a shell-builtin `test` implementation be used and are targeting a ksh-family shell such as bash, `[[` is the better choice: Even though modern shells _do_ generally have built-in `[` implementations, that's generally a performance enhancement and the only standard-guaranteed behaviors are those specified for `/usr/bin/[`, which (as an external command) can't see shell variables and [isn't specified](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) to have a `-v`.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need the $ when checking if it is set and so:

```
if [[ ! -v VAR ]]; then
    echo "unset"
else 
    echo "set: $VAR"
fi
```

Comment: Can you explain why it works when we don't use `$` ?

Comment: $ normally expands a variable or command. In this instance, we are not expanding.

Comment: It's not that you can't use `$`, but that the argument to `-v` is supposed to take the name of a variable as its argument. If you want to check if `VAR` is set, then `VAR`, not the expansion of `$VAR`, is the argument you want.