# how to print environment variable value in shell of a variable whose name is present in another variable value

Tags: shell

I have store environment variable names in an array with name array and I want to check if it is set then only certain code should run.
Like if somebody has set environment variable *db_instance_type="t2.micro"* then desire output should be  *-var="db_instance_type=$db_instance_type"*

I have written below code but it is not working as expected because I am checking variable presence using single $ which will always be there and not checking main variable value.

```
set -u
db_instance_type="t2.micro" # for testing only
db_dns_ttl="300"    # for testing only
function check_input_vars() {
    local temp_cmd=''

    declare -a array=(db_instance_type db_vpc_id db_subnet_ids db_sg_cidr_allowed_range db_ebs_volume_size delete_on_termination_db_ebs_volume
                    security_group_id contact db_image_owner_id db_dns_ttl db_image_name_filter ws_key_name ws_dns_ttl ws_instance_type
                    ws_vpc_id  ws_subnet_ids ws_ami_id enable_ws_public_ip
                    )

    temp_cmd=''
    for var in "${array[@]}"
    do
        var_name=(${!var@})
        if [[ "${var_name}" ]]; then 
            temp_cmd+=" -var=\"$var=\$$var\""
        fi
    done   
    echo $temp_cmd
}

input_var_str="$(check_input_vars)"
echo "$input_var_str"  # output should be: -var="db_instance_type=$db_instance_type" -var="db_dns_ttl=$db_dns_ttl
unset db_instance_type  # for testing only
```

Fix:

I have to comment this line --> #set -u
And I have used below code:

```
var_value=${!var}
if [[ ! -z "${var_value}" ]]; then temp_cmd+=" -var=\"$var=\$$var\""; fi
```

Comment: Subjectively: This sounds like a bad idea. I believe using so many global variables will only result in unmaintanable spaghetti code. `unset db_instance_type  # for testing only` spagetti.

Comment: You want the output to be exactly literally `-var="db_instance_type=$db_instance_type"` __or__ do you want the output ot be `-var="db_instance_type=t2.micro"`? You specified the first, so the command works like you want, so? Also why do you want to have `"` in the string - are you sure you want quotes preserved literally?

Comment: output should be: -var="db_instance_type=$db_instance_type" -var="db_dns_ttl=$db_dns_ttl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is off - to get the variable value use `${!var}`. No `@`. And `(` `)` are for array assignment - it's not an array, it's a single vlaue.

```
    var_value=${!var}
    if [[ -n "${var_value}" ]]; then..
```

Also, it accesses the value of the variable, where variable `var` stores the name of the variable, thus I would call the variable `var_value`.

Check your scripts with https://shellcheck.net .

To protect against `set -u`, expand variable to empty when not defined or empty.

```
 var_value=${!var:-}
```

Also:  [How to check if a variable is set in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash)

---

> output should be: -var="db_instance_type=$db_instance_type" -var="db_dns_ttl=$db_dns_ttl"

Related reading: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048 https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006 .

Comment: I am not getting right output and also getting an error.
!var: unbound variable
(blank)

Comment: Hi @kmilChuk, I figure out whats the issue here. The issue is` set -u` . When I removed it it work fine otherwise it fail.