# I found VARIABLE="${VARIABLE:-""}" at the very begin of a bash script, cannot understand what :- is doing here

Tags: bash, shell

I need to install a product for Linux that comes with an `install.sh` script. Before running it I want to understand what it will do to my system. At the very begin of the script there is something like `VARIABLE="${VARIABLE:-""}"`. I know `${VARIABLE}` is reference to access the content of the variable `VARIABLE`. But I really don't know the purpose of `:-""` Can you help me please?

Comment: `${var:-other}` set to `var` if `var` is set, otherwise the default `other` is used.. So `v1="${v2:-""}"` set `v1=v2` if `v2` is set, otherwise it sets `v1=""`. Think about how you can set a default or use the first program argument `$1`. `myvar="${1:-some_default}"`.

Comment: For all the variable operators, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash/16753536#16753536

Comment: See: [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)