# Generating x509 certificate - bash getting stuck and not doing/showing anything

Tags: openssl, git-bash, x509certificate, private-key

I was working on creating x509 certificate running openssl commands. First, I have this command to generate encrypted private key:

```
openssl genrsa -passout pass:MyPwd -aes256 -out privkey.key 2048
```

After that, I want to generate a certificate using this key. At first, I tried running this command (cert-config.config is a config file with pre-filled prompts for the certificate):

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key privkey.key -out cert.csr -config cert-config.config
```

But executing this results in the Bash just getting stuck, it doesn't show me anything, doesn't respond (i tried typing the password and pressing enter, no result). I hade to go to cmd and taskkill the execution of this command, because it literally just got stuck.

I tried passing in the password, so now I ran this command:

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key privkey.key -out cert.csr -config cert-config.config -passout pass:MyPwd
```

And had the same result. I want to mention that when I generated the private key WITHOUT encrypting it, I didn't have that issue (I guess that is because without encryption it wasn't asking for a password -> wasn't freezing).
My guess is that even though I try to pass the password to the command, bash still asks for the password, but doesn't show me the actual prompt. But, like I said before, I tried typing the password and pressing enter and nothing happened.
Does anyone know what I could do?

Comment: Yes that command will try to ask the password, and in git/Windows 'git-bash' (presumably somewhere between openssl, cygwin pty handling, and mintty) it fails. You can avoid the prompt on `req -new -key` by using **`-passin` (_not_ `-passout`** as used on `genrsa`). You could also use an OpenSSL whose prompting does work on Windows, like the one in WSL/Ubuntu (on Win 10 up) or the native-Windows package from http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html .

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you so much! I tried using passin before and for some reason I got errors, but it worked now! Still having problems with the last step of my script where I generate a pfx certifiate: openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey privkey.key -in cert.crt -passin pass:MyPwd, the bash is getting stuck there now :c

Comment: `pkcs12 -export` needs _two_ passwords: one to read the input privkey if encrypted, one to write the output (always) which _may_ be same value but entered separately: **use _both_ `-passin` and `-passout`** (for `pkcs12` command _only_ you can use `-password` instead of `-passout` on export or `-passin` on import, but that's more work to remember for no benefit so don't)