# Cannot Export Key or Cert files from PFX file

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, pfx

I am working to generate the proper security files for Tableau Server. I have installed a certificate on our server and exported the .pfx file. After exporting the PFX file, I try to export the kef file and convert the .pfx file to a certificate, using Open SSL in Gitbash. This process fails. .key and .crt files are created, but they are empty (OKB). When I close Gitbash, I receive an error:

```
Processes are running in the session:
|WPID PID COMMAND
|17216 547 "C:\Program\Git\mingw
```

I use the following commands to generate the key file and cert.

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in [filename.pfx] -nocerts -passout pass:[password] -out [keyfile.key]
$ openssl pkcs12 -in [filename.pfx] -clcerts -nokeys -out [certificate.crt]
```

I've opened the .pfx file and it does have a key and three certs.

Any insight into what may be causing the problem?

Comment: Do you get, and answer, prompt `Enter Import Password:` for each command? [Another user recently reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72524858/generating-x509-certificate-bash-getting-stuck-and-not-doing-showing-anything) the openssl in git-bash failing to prompt, and I can reproduce with (slightly old) git4win 2.23.0.2 on Win 10. If so avoid the prompt by supplying the import password with `-passin` the same way you already supply the output password with `-passout`. Or use a different build of openssl, like WSL or ShiningLight.

Comment: I've tried both methods. I've used -passin and -passout, and waited for the password prompt. When I wait for the password prompt, it never shows up.

I'll take a look into a new build of openssl. Thanks for the recommendation.