# I can't export any certificate to PKCS 12, Could not read private key / openssl program

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, pfx

I can't export domain signed certificate, with the command:
`openssl pkcs12 -export -in domain.crt -inkey domain.key -out domain.pfx`
It pops up for me:

```
Could not read private key from -inkey file from domain.key
FC210000:error:1608010C:STORE routines:ossl_store_handle_load_result:unsupported:..\crypto\store\store_result.c:151:
FC210000:error:1C800064:Provider routines:ossl_cipher_unpadblock:bad decrypt:..\providers\implementations\ciphers\ciphercommon_block.c:124:
FC210000:error:11800074:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_pbe_crypt_ex:pkcs12 cipherfinal error:..\crypto\pkcs12\p12_decr.c:86:empty password
```

I have my own certification authority certificate which is valid. I would like to export my regular certificate and sign it with this CA. But I can't do that because I can't export domain signed certificate.
I use OpenSSL on Windows 11 Pro for home users. I know it should be done through the server but I don't want to install it additionally
I simply wanted to export the certificate with the private key to PFX via openssl. I received the error described exactly above:
`Could not read private key from -inkey file from domain.key`.

I was expecting a successful export and subsequent signing of the certificate (if I had to) by an existing self-signed (it's in the CA trusted certificate store) CA certificate

Comment: This is probably not programming or development, but: `openssl` likely got the wrong password for the input keyfile (`domain.key`) and clearly got a wrong (empty) password for the output pkcs12 file. Were you prompted for these passwords and did you enter them correctly? What package or build of OpenSSL are you running? Are you using traditional console, WinTerm, CMD, PS, something else? In `domain.key` is the first line `-----BEGIN xxx-----` and what exactly is `xxx`? Do the second and third lines begin `Proc-type:` and `DEK-info`? PS: what kind of CA takes a PKCS12 as _input_??

Comment: @dave_thompson_085
1. No, I was not asked for any password. Immediately after entering the command, an error appeared about the inability to read the key file. 
2. openssl-3.0.7-0-g19cc035b6c x64
3. Yes, i use CMD
4. -----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY----- is first line, 2 and 3 line is random chairs
5. I generated the CA certificate myself (via openssl). In the Command, however, there is nothing about signing through it. However, the same problem arises with exporting it to PFX as with the CSR to CRT here

Comment: Are you using (the openssl in) git-bash (for Windows)? I didn't remember details initially but that apparently doesn't prompt for passwords when it should: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72524858/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72539123/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67275008/ . If so try either running under `winpty` or using options `-passin` and `-passout`. Even in something else like WSL or cygwin or gnuwin, `-passin -passout` may well help.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085I tried with -passin and -passout or with just this and this. But I kept getting this pop up:
Invalid password argument, missing ":" in the first 5 characters.
On the other hand, when I gave such a two-character before 5 characters and on the 5th character: Invalid password argument, starting with "w:"
Error getting passwords
Followed by the same as above. I tried the same thing on other consoles, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: To specify an actual password value (rather than from an envvar or file) with `-passin -passout -password` you must make the argument `pass:` PLUS the actual value. That's why and how there's a colon in the first 5 chars. See [the man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl.html#Pass-Phrase-Options).