# No prompt from Git Bash

Tags: openssl, git-bash

I am using Git Bash for the following command:

openssl pkcs12 -export -nokeys -in certificate.cer -out pkcs12.pfx

There should be a prompt asking me to enter export password, but it just stay there and no prompt coming out.
How do I get the prompt so that it continue the rest? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67275008/in-git-bash-windows-openssl-pkcs12-does-not-prompt-for-password also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72524858/generating-x509-certificate-bash-getting-stuck-and-not-doing-showing-anything https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72539123/cannot-export-key-or-cert-files-from-pfx-file