# How can I make bash warn undefined variables but still run script?

Tags: bash

Is there a way to make bash warn if a variable is undefined but prevent script execution from aborting?
I'm looking for something similar to `set -u`, except that `set -u` aborts execution and I would like the script to warn, but continue execution when it finds undefined variables.
I know I can [check whether a variable is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash) , but my scripts have hundred of variables and I'm looking for a solution that avoids checking variables one by one.

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) can tell you before you run the script.

Comment: What's your intent in warning about unset variables? I don't think there's a simple runtime option to do this without aborting but depending on your goal maybe there's another solution.

Comment: @tjm3772 my script is scheduled to run overnight, and it makes reference to variables that are defined on other files. My intent in warning is that I can periodically check log of execution and know if my script tried to use any undefined variable so that I can fix any typo on the script or define the variable properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$ cat /tmp/q.sh
#!/bin/bash

set -u

echo 1
echo $2
echo 3

$ bash --norc --noprofile --noediting -i /tmp/q.sh
1
bash: $2: unbound variable
3
```

That is, force interactive mode (`-i`) when running the script, which prevents bash from aborting with `set -u`, but you have to also use `--norc --noprofile --noediting` (maybe some things more?), to make it behave more like a non-interactive shell.

I can't tell if this is expected or unexpected behavior, though (it doesn't work when using `-c`). Works on versions 4.2.46(2)-release (Oracle Linux 7), 4.1.2(1)-release (Oracle Linux 6) and 5.1.16(1)-release (Arch Linux).