# how to check if in bin/sh evironment variable is set

Tags: bash

using /bin/sh how to check if environment variable is set.

The below command works for /bin/bash but not for /bin/sh

```
if [[ -v PROXY_PASS_MAPPING ]]; then echo "set" fi
```

what command will work for /bin/sh

Comment: Doesn't https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash answer your question?

Comment: @KamilCuk : The question which you are linking to, deals about how to test for a **variable** to be defined, while the OP wants to know whether a variable is in the **environment**. Admittedly, this point is missing in the OP's bash solution as well.

Comment: @kumar: Even in bash, you don't test for **environment** variables, but just for **variables** to be set. For verifying the environment in bash **and** POSIX shell, use `printenv`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work for POSIX shell and bash:

```
if [ -n "$(printenv PROXY_PASS_MAPPING)" ]
then 
  echo The Variable is not empty and in the environment
fi
```

This does not catch the case where the variable is in the environment **and** empty. To test this, you can use

```
if printenv PROXY_PASS_MAPPING >/dev/null
then
  echo The Variable is in the environment
else
  echo The variable is not in the environment
fi
```