# test: -v: unary operator expected

Tags: bash, shell, github-actions

I try to run such code via "github actions"

```
      - name: Run tests
        run: |
          set -e
          ...
          test -v A || export B=42
        shell: bash
```

and got error at line `test -v A || export B=42`:

```
test: -v: unary operator expected
```

I have no idea what is this about,
if I run this command in my local bash all works as expected,
what is wrong in my yaml code for "github actions"?

Comment: Not directly related to your question: `set -e` is redundant. See [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].shell`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By any chance does your test happen to be running under a macOS CI environment? `test -v` tests if a variable has been set, but, it was only added in Bash 4.2.

macOS by default comes with Bash 3.2, and that's the expected error if it doesn't recognize `-v` as a unary operator.

To fix this, you can install the latest Bash, or use a [different approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash) for testing for existence:

```bash
[ -z "${A+x}" ] && export B=42
```

Comment: Edited to add quotes. Without them, you get `[ -z ]` instead of `[ -z '' ]` in the unset case; sure, they're both true, but they're true _for different reasons_, as `[ -z ]` is equivalent to `[ -n "-z" ]`

Comment: You might also want to add the link of the GHA [Preinstalled Software](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#preinstalled-software) in your answer to reference those different Bash versions.