# "Conditional binary operator expected" from [[ -v varname ]] in bash 3.2 (MacOS)

Tags: bash

I have a very simple bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ -v USE_ALB ]]; then
    echo "The environmental variable exists."
else
    echo "The environmental variable does not exist."
fi
```

I run this and get the error `line 28: conditional binary operator expected`

I also tried

```
if [[ -v "${USE_ALB}" ]]; then
  echo -e "\ndefined\n"
fi
```

and still get same error

My shell version is:

```
bash --version echo $?
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin22)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

How can I check that one environmental variable exists ?

I want to use them as named arguments for example `USE_ALB=1 bash script.sh` and do something if USE_ALB is defined

Comment: fwiw, I don't get any error messages with `bash v 4.4.12` or `bash v 5.1.16`

Comment: You could just do `if [[ ${USE_ALB+x} ]]` for that; no reason to mess with `-v` for this simple a case.

Comment: The `-v` conditional operator doesn't exist in Bash 3.x, it was added in Bash 4.x.

Comment: (and you do notice the 2007 copyright date on bash 3.2, right? It only exists in the modern day because Apple refuses to ship any software that would obligate them to comply with GPLv3 licensing terms).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a variable is set in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of `bash` doesn't appear to support the `-v` test. You can replicate it with a parameter expansion though:

```
if [[ "${USE_ALB+x}" ]] ; then
  : # USE_ALB is set
else
  : # USE_ALB is not set
fi
```

`${var+x}` expands to `x` when var is set, and expands to nothing if var is null or unset. This lets you test its existence based on whether the resulting expansion is empty or not.

Comment: Thanks this works. My question is, is your solution going to work on other bash versions in plain linux/ubuntu as well ?

Comment: It will work in any bash version as far as I'm aware, and in any POSIX-compliant shell if you replace `[[ ]]` with `[ ]`.