# In Bash, how do I test if a variable is defined in "-u" mode

Tags: bash

I just discovered `set -u` in bash and it helped me find several previously unseen bugs. But I also have a scenario where I need to test if a variable is defined before computing some default value. The best I have come up with for this is:

```
if [ "${variable-undefined}" == undefined ]; then
    variable="$(...)"
fi
```

which works (as long as the variable doesn't have the string value `undefined`).  I was wondering if there was a better way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test if a variable is set in bash when using "set -o nounset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832080/how-to-test-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash-when-using-set-o-nounset)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

#### What Doesn't Work: Test for Zero-Length Strings

You can test for undefined strings in a few ways. Using the standard test conditional looks like this:

```
# Test for zero-length string.
[ -z "$variable" ] || variable='foo'
```

This will not work with `set -u`, however.

#### What Works: Conditional Assignment

Alternatively, you can use conditional assignment, which is a more Bash-like way to do this. For example:

```
# Assign value if variable is unset or null.
: "${variable:=foo}"
```

Because of the way Bash handles expansion of this expression, you can safely use this with `set -u` without getting a "bash: variable: unbound variable" error.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question as it doesn't provide a way to test for an undefined variable, simply a way to set it if it is. If other logic is desired, this won't help.

Comment: This answer appears to be more suitable for simply doing a test: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56846/18985

Comment: @AndrewFerrier This question specifically refers to assigning a default value if the variable is unset; while there are valid use cases for testing if a variable is set without subsequently setting it, this question does not require it.

Comment: what is that leading `:` doing ?

Comment: @PypeBros apparently `:` is aliased to true: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin

Comment: so ... `: $COMMAND` would evaluate to true whatever the outcome of the command ? a bit like `- COMMAND` with makefiles ?

Comment: Pragmatically, the leading `:` provides the shell a way to perform expansions that set values without having to use more verbose constructs like `[[ -z "$variable" ]] || variable='foo'`. You also need it in places where a simple comment wouldn't parse properly, like an empty action in an if-then statement such as `if true; then; fi` (which raises `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`;'`),  rather than `if true; then :; fi` (which runs without errors).

Answer (score 73):

This is what I've found works best for me, taking inspiration from the other answers:

```
if [ -z "${varname-}" ]; then
  ...
  varname=$(...)
fi
```

Comment: Can someone explain why `"${varname-}"` **and** `"${varname:-}"` works?  I am surprised the first works.

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html
${varname-} is a form of ${varname-default}. If varname is not set the default is returned, in this case an empty string.

Comment: The colon-free versions are described in a quick sentence in the man page just before the various operators are described. It's easy to miss. `${varname:-foo}` expands to `foo` if `varname` is unset *or* set to the empty string; `${varname-foo}` only expands to `foo` if `varname` is unset.

Comment: This still can't distinguish a variable that is set to empty value vs. a variable that is undefined.

Answer (score 11):

In bash 4.2 and newer there is an explicit way to check whether a variable is set, which is to use -v.
The example from the question could then be implemented like this:

```
if [[ ! -v variable ]]; then
   variable="$(...)"
fi
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions

If you only want to set the variable, if it is not already set you are probably better of doing something along these lines:

`variable="${variable-$(...)}"`

Note that this does not deal with a defined but empty variable.

Comment: Keep in mind that `-v` was not added to `bash` until version 4.2.

Answer (score 5):

The answers above are not dynamic, e.g., how to test is variable with name "dummy" is defined?  Try this:

```
is_var_defined()
{
    if [ $# -ne 1 ]
    then
        echo "Expected exactly one argument: variable name as string, e.g., 'my_var'"
        exit 1
    fi
    # Tricky.  Since Bash option 'set -u' may be enabled, we cannot directly test if a variable
    # is defined with this construct: [ ! -z "$var" ].  Instead, we must use default value
    # substitution with this construct: [ ! -z "${var:-}" ].  Normally, a default value follows the
    # operator ':-', but here we leave it blank for empty (null) string.  Finally, we need to
    # substitute the text from $1 as 'var'.  This is not allowed directly in Bash with this
    # construct: [ ! -z "${$1:-}" ].  We need to use indirection with eval operator.
    # Example: $1="var"
    # Expansion for eval operator: "[ ! -z \${$1:-} ]" -> "[ ! -z \${var:-} ]"
    # Code  execute: [ ! -z ${var:-} ]
    eval "[ ! -z \${$1:-} ]"
    return $?  # Pedantic.
}
```

Related: [How to check if a variable is set in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3601515/257299)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `[[ -n $var ]]` or `[[ $var ]]` instead of `[ ! -z "$var" ]`? Also FYI Bash has support for variable indirection since v2, so there is no need for eval here. E.g. `is_var_defined(){ if (( $# != 1 )); then echo "Expected exactly one argument: variable name as string, e.g., 'my_var'" >&2; return 1; fi; [[ -n ${!1:-} ]]; }`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly `[[ -v variable ]]` is not supported in older versions of bash (at least not in version 4.1.5 I have on Debian Squeeze)

You could instead use a sub shell as in this :

```
if (true $variable)&>/dev/null; then
    variable="$(...)"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning of your script, you could define your variables with an empty value

```
variable_undefined=""
```

Then

```
if [ "${variable_undefined}" == "" ]; then
    variable="$(...)"
fi
```

Comment: Dashes aren't valid variable name characters. It's part of the parameter expansion syntax that the OP is using.

Comment: Then it is better to test with -z to check if the size of the string is zero

Comment: @coelhuedo ...but you can't expand an undefined variable in `set -u` mode in order to run it through `test -z`, hence this question.

Comment: I like this way of getting around the problem because it forces you to 'declare' your variables at the top of your script.

Comment: This doesn't work when you need to use environment variables set by other processes.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ "${var+SET}" = "SET" ] ; then
    echo "\$var = ${var}"
fi
```

I don't know how far back ${var+value} is supported, but it works at least as far back as 4.1.2. Older versions didn't have ${var+value}, they only had ${var:+value}. The difference is that ${var:+value} will only evaluate to "value" if $var is set to a **nonempty** string, while ${var+value} will also evaluate to "value" if $var is set to the empty string.

Without [[ -v var ]] or ${var+value} I think you'd have to use another method. Probably a subshell test as was described in a previous answer:

```
if ( set -u; echo "$var" ) &> /dev/null; then
    echo "\$var = ${var}
fi
```

If your shell process has "set -u" active already it'll be active in the subshell as well without the need for "set -u" again, but including it in the subshell command allows the solution to also work if the parent process hasn't got "set -u" enabled.

(You could also use another process like "printenv" or "env" to test for the presence of the variable, but then it'd only work if the variable is exported.)