# Handling unused getopts argument

Tags: bash, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, getopts

I have a script that starts with getopts and looks as follows:

```
USAGE() { echo -e "Usage: bash $0 [-w <in-dir>] [-o <out-dir>] [-c <template1>] [-t <template2>] \n" 1>&2; exit 1; }

if (($# == 0))
then
    USAGE
fi

while getopts ":w:o:c:t:h" opt
do
    case $opt in
        w ) BIGWIGS=$OPTARG
        ;;
        o ) OUTDIR=$OPTARG
        ;;
        c ) CONTAINER=$OPTARG
        ;;
        t ) TRACK=$OPTARG
        ;;
        h ) USAGE
        ;;
        \? ) echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG exiting" >&2
        exit
        ;;
        : ) echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument" >&2
        exit
        ;;
    esac
done

more commands etc

echo $OUTDIR
echo $CONTAINER
```

I am fairly new to getopts. I was doing some testing on this script and at some stage, I didn't need/want to use the -c argument [-c ]. In other words, I was trying to test another specific part of the script not involving the $CONTAINER variable at all. Therefore, I simply added # in front of all commands with the $CONTAINER and did some testing which was fine.

When testing the script without using $CONTAINER, I typed:

```
bash script.bash -w mydir -o myoutdir -t mywantedtemplate
```

However, I was wondering, given my getopts command I didn't get a warning. In other words, why did I not get a warning asking for -c argument. Is this possible? Does the warning only occur if I type:

```
bash script.bash -w mydir -o myoutdir -t mywantedtemplate -c
```

**UPDATE**

After doing some testing, I think that is it:

- If you don't explicitly write "-c", getopts won't "ask" you for it and give you an error (unless your script is doing something with it - i.e. if you haven't put # in front of each command using this argument)
- You only get an error if you put "-c  "

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getopts` does not warn when some options are not used (i.e. they are *optional*).  Usually that's a good thing because some options (e.g. `-h`) are not used with other options.  There is no way to specify mandatory options directly with the Bash builtin `getopts`.  If you want mandatory options then you will need to write code to check that they have been used.  See [bash getopts with multiple and mandatory options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11279423/4154375).  Also (as you have found), you won't get an error if you fail to write code to handle options specified in the `optstring` (first) argument to `getopts`.

You could get a kind of automatic warning for mandatory arguments by using the `nounset` setting in your Bash code (with `set -o nounset` or `set -u`).  That would cause warnings to be issued for code like `echo $CONTAINER` if the `-c` option is not specified so `$CONTAINER` is not set.  However, using the `nounset` option would mean that **all** of your code needs to be written more carefully.  See [How can I make bash treat undefined variables as errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41020844/4154375), including the comments and "Linked" answers, for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You might use this script:

`printf` captures the `stdout` and put into the `stderr` and then back to the `stdout` also captures the `exit` code, so we can handle if the code is greater than `0`.

```sh
some_command() {
    echo 'this is the stdout'
    echo 'this is the stderr' >&2
    exit 1
}

run_command() {
    {
        IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' stderr;
        IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' stdout;
        (IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' _ERRNO_; exit ${_ERRNO_});
    } < <((printf '\0%s\0%d\0' "$(some_command)" "${?}" 1>&2) 2>&1)
}

echo 'Run command:'
if ! run_command; then
    ## Show the values
    typeset -p stdout stderr
else
    typeset -p stdout stderr
fi
```

Just replace `some_command` with `getopts ":w:o:c:t:h"`