# how to write if $var == *

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have a script that I'm writing and I've set some flags using If statements.
for example my flags are set as

```
flag=$(-a,-b,-c,-d)
```

and for example my If statement is set as

```
if echo "$flag" | grep -q -E -o "(-)(a)"; then
        1
fi
```

my question is how do I add another if statement that will say if flag does not exist, then show an error.
I've tried something like the following but it does not work.

```
if "[[ $flag"=="*" ]]; then
        Error.
fi
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Does `flag=$(-a,-b,-c,-d)` really work? Do you mean `flag=(-a,-b,-c,-d)`?

Comment: @md2perpe yeah sorry the $ sign was a typo..
the main thing though is how to write if someone entered -k for example and it will notify him its a wrong input.

Comment: I removed the tag "flags" because your issue just happens to be with a variable *named* "flags", not flags *per se*. I also removed the "Linux" tag because bash is not just on Linux.

Comment: @DevSolar Okay thanks!
I'm a bit new to bash scripting so thanks for the assistance with the tags :)

Answer (score 0):

"If flag does not exist" -- like, `flag` not being defined?

You could treat **all** [undefined variables as errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020844).

Or you could [check if the variable is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/).

Comment: I mean if flag not being defind.
if someone wrote -k which is not part of $flag it should notify its an error.

Answer (score 0):

`bash` suggests a solution with its own `$-` variable.

Store each flag as a single character in a string:

```
flags="abcd"
```

then use pattern-matching to determine if a particular flag is set or not:

```
if [[ $flags = *a* ]]; then
    echo "a is set"
else
    echo "a is not set"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I'm only using If for each flag so I'll be able to use several flags together.
When I've used If-elif-else it only takes the first flag that was set.