# How to test if variable is set and not empty, when using “set -o nounset”

Tags: bash, shell

Yes there is a similar thread here: [Test if a variable is set in bash when using "set -o nounset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832080/test-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash-when-using-set-o-nounset)

However there are so many different answers that it's not particularly clear.

Would the following be sufficient to test if a variable is set AND not empty?

```
#!/bin/bash 
set -o nounset

if [[ ! -z "${EXAMPLE-}" ]]; then
    echo "Variable is defined and is not empty..."
fi
```

Comment: This is covered by [BashFAQ #112](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112).

Comment: BashFAQ #112 could use an update; it doesn't mention the `-v` operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, `[[ ! -z "${EXAMPLE-}" ]]` safely determines whether the variable named `EXAMPLE` has a non-empty value assigned, even with `set -u` active.

Personally, I would write `[[ -n "${EXAMPLE-}" ]]` or even `[[ ${EXAMPLE-} ]]` -- taking advantage of additional terseness made safe by `[[ ]]` and not trustworthy with `[ ]` -- but all these are correct.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `-v` operator to check if a name has been set to a value:

```
if [[ -v EXAMPLE ]]; then
    echo "Safe to expand: $EXAMPLE"
fi
```

Comment: Notice that this requires Bash 4.2 or newer.