# Script exits with error when var=$(... | grep "value") is empty, but works when grep has results

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following bash code (running on Red Hat) that is exiting when I enable `set -o errexit` and the variable in the code is empty, BUT works fine when the variable is set; the code is designed to test if a screen session matching `.monitor_*` exists, and if so do something.

I have the following turned on:

```
set -o errexit
set -x xtrace; PS4='$LINENO: '
```

If there is a session matching the above pattern it works; however, if nothing matches it just exits with no information other than the following output from xtrace

```
someuser:~/scripts/tests> ./if_test.sh
+ ./if_test.sh
+ PS4='$LINENO: '
4: set -o errexit
5: set -o pipefail
6: set -o nounset
88: /usr/bin/ls -lR /var/run/uscreens/S-storage-rsync
88: grep '.monitor_*'
88: awk '{ print $9 }'
88: /usr/bin/grep -Ev 'total|uscreens'
8: ms=
```

I tested the command I am using to set the `ms` var and it agrees with the xtrace output, it's not set.

```
someuser:~/scripts/tests> test -n "${mn}"
+ test -n ''
```

I have tried using a select statement and got the same results... I can't figure it out, anyone able to help? Thanks.

I read through all the possible solution recommendations, nothing seems to address my issue.

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o xtrace; PS4='$LINENO: '
set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset

ms="$(/usr/bin/ls -lR /var/run/uscreens/S-"${USER}" | /usr/bin/grep -Ev "total|uscreens" | grep ".monitor_*" | awk '{ print $9 }')"

if [[ -z "${ms}" ]]; then
    echo "Handling empty result"
elif [[ -n "${ms}" ]]; then
    echo "Handling non-empty result"
fi
```

The following answer was proposed: [Test if a variable is set in bash when using "set -o nounset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832080/test-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash-when-using-set-o-nounset); however, it doesn't address the issue at all. In my case the variable being tested is set and as stated in my detail, it's set to `""`, or nothing. Thank you; however, it doesn't help.

It really seems to be the variable declaration that it isn't liking.

```
ms="$(/usr/bin/ls -lR /var/run/uscreens/S-"${USER}" | /usr/bin/grep -Ev "total|uscreens" | grep ".monitor_*" | awk '{ print $9 }')"
```

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832080/test-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash-when-using-set-o-nounset

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test if a variable is set in bash when using "set -o nounset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832080/test-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash-when-using-set-o-nounset)

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue, thank you. It has something to do with the variable being set via a command I think. I am still working on this - but the above linked answer doesn't answer it thank you.

Comment: You're running `set -o pipefail`. When `grep` doesn't match anything, it has a nonzero exit status, and with `pipefail`, that fails the entire pipeline. This is all behaving exactly the way you're telling your shell it *should* behave.

Comment: BTW, before deciding to use `set -o errexit`, I *strongly* suggest going through the exercises in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises).

Comment: Thank you Charles. I will do that. I appreciate the help. Do you have any suggestions for resolving my snafu?

Comment: Well, my *main* suggestion is not to use `set -e`. You can, of course, always add a conditional to the specific pipeline component(s).

Comment: Charles was spot on, thank you. I commented out set -o pipefail, and it confirmed what he said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You're running `set -o pipefail`, so if any component in a pipeline has a nonzero exit status, the entire pipeline is treated as having a nonzero exit status.
- Your pipeline runs `grep`. `grep` has a nonzero status whenever no matches are found.
- You're running `set -o errexit` (aka `set -e`). With `errexit` enabled, the script terminates whenever any command fails (subject to a long and complicated set of exceptions; some of these are presented in [the exercises section of BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises), and others touched on in [this excellent reference](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/)).

Thus, when you have no matches in your `grep` command, your script terminates on the command substitution running the pipeline in question.

---

If you want to exempt a specific command from `set -e`'s behavior, the easiest way to do it is to simply append `||:` (shorthand for `|| true`), which marks the command as "checked".

Comment: For those still learning or needing more detail on exactly how Charles' answer applies to my code, I modified my variable to apply the `|| true` to it (full var shown above: ```... grep ".monitor_*" | awk '{ print $9 }' || true)"``` Or, ```... grep ".monitor_*" | awk '{ print $9 }' ||:)"```

Comment: Consider `awk '/total|uscreens/ && /.monitor_*/ { print $9 }'`, getting rid of the `grep`s altogether.

Comment: ...that said, do note that [parsing `ls` output is itself best avoided](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 1):

"You're running set -o pipefail. When grep doesn't match anything, it has a nonzero exit status, and with pipefail, that fails the entire pipeline. This is all behaving exactly the way you're telling your shell it should behave." – Charles Duffy

Charles above comment was exactly what was going on, my script was working as intended and I need to adjust the logic to work differently if I wish to keep `set -o pipefail` set.

Thank you for the help.