# Checking If Unix Parameter is Non-Empty

Tags: shell, unix, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to tell if a string is not defined in a bash shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228544/how-to-tell-if-a-string-is-not-defined-in-a-bash-shell-script)
>   [What’s the best way to check that environment variables are set in Unix shellscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307503/whats-the-best-way-to-check-that-environment-variables-are-set-in-unix-shellscr)

I'm trying my hand at Unix shell scripting for the first time and in a script I'm working on now, I want 2 of the 3 arguments to my script to be optional. However, if the user doesn't enter the arguments, I need to use default values. How can I properly say something that basically means:

```
$argument = $2
if($argument  == "")
    $argument = "defaultVal"
```

Thanks!

Comment: `if [ "x$2" == "x" ]; then $argument="default"; fi`

Comment: I thought `$#` stored the number of input params? I could be wrong.

Comment: `test -n` or `test -z` . Test is almost the same as `[`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to check that environment variables are set in Unix shellscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307503/whats-the-best-way-to-check-that-environment-variables-are-set-in-unix-shellscr), or you might prefer [How to tell if a string is not defined in a Bash shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228544/how-to-tell-if-a-string-is-not-defined-in-a-bash-shell-script/230593#230593)

Comment: It is vitally important to say *which* shell you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if [ "x$2" == "x" ]; then
    $argument="default";
else
    $argument=$2;
fi
```

Comment: Is that trick still necessary? `if [ "$2" = "" ];` works fine, in `bash` and `dash` at least.

Comment: @chepner I had problems with the "" being recognized as an empty token producing a syntax error, so I'd say yes.

Comment: Both these answers seem to work great - I just accepted the first one I got working! Thanks to both of you for your quick replies!

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
argument=${2:-default value}
```

Comment: Both these answers seem to work great - I just accepted the first one I got working! Thanks to both of you for your quick replies!