# Variable which indicates which part of script run

Tags: linux, bash, sh

Inside script I have SQL queries which I execute. But I would like to do a variable which indicates what exact SQL script I want to run. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

SQL1 = "Select * from dual"

SQL1 = "Select sysdate from dual"

SQL3 = "Select sysdate+1 from dual"
```

Now, I would like to run a script eg. `./script.sh 2` - > which indicates that I want to run second SQL query.

Probably the easiest way is to do it this way:

```
if [ $1 = 1 ] then
SQL1 = "Select * from dual"
if [ $1 = 2] then
SQL2 = "Select sysdate from dual"
if [ $1 = 3] then
SQL3 = "Select sysdate+1 from dual"
fi fi fi
```

Now, the question is, what if I want to run all of them, so I will run my script: `./script.sh` (without variable).

I know I cant use [-z] but, I don't want to repeat SQL queries eg.

```
if [ $1 = 1 ] then
    SQL1 = "Select * from dual"
    if [ $1 = 2] then
    SQL2 = "Select sysdate from dual"
    if [ $1 = 3] then
    SQL3 = "Select sysdate+1 from dual"
    fi fi fi
if [ -z $1 ] then
SQL1 = "Select * from dual"
```

and so on...
How to handle with that ?

Comment: use logical or in every if condition. Check if $1 is empty or has value x

Comment: Ok so, if [-z "1" or $1 = 1] - right ?

Comment: Yeah. That should do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use an array and check if the index exists or not and act accordingly?

See it just printing:

```
#!/bin/bash

commands=("SELECT 1" "SELECT 2" "SELECT 3")
line=$(($1 - 1))
[ "${commands[$line]+abc}" ] && echo "${commands[$line]}" || printf "%s\n" "${commands[@]}"
```

This uses the nice trick to [check an index or a key in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13221491/1983854).

Let's execute it:

```
$ ./myscript.sh 5
SELECT 1
SELECT 2
SELECT 3
$ ./myscript.sh 2
SELECT 2
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check the number of arg instead of -z.

`if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then .....`